# kbhit() on MacOS to detect keypress

Tags: c++, macos

I am new to C++ on MacOS.
I got an error when I used `kbhit()` in my program.

I used `#include<conio.h>` but got error too, so I searched and test with `#include<curses.h>` but error is still remained.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code that is producing the error, and the error message

Comment: See my answer to a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input#448982

Answer (score 2):

No idea if this would work on Mac, but here's some code that I've used to get a single keypress on Linux.

```
int mygetch() {
    char ch;
    int error;
    static struct termios Otty, Ntty;

    fflush(stdout);
    tcgetattr(0, &Otty);
    Ntty = Otty;

    Ntty.c_iflag  =  0;     /* input mode       */
    Ntty.c_oflag  =  0;     /* output mode      */
    Ntty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;    /* line settings    */

#if 1
    /* disable echoing the char as it is typed */
    Ntty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;  /* disable echo     */
#else
    /* enable echoing the char as it is typed */
    Ntty.c_lflag |=  ECHO;  /* enable echo      */
#endif

    Ntty.c_cc[VMIN]  = CMIN;    /* minimum chars to wait for */
    Ntty.c_cc[VTIME] = CTIME;   /* minimum wait time    */

#if 1
    /*
    * use this to flush the input buffer before blocking for new input
    */
    #define FLAG TCSAFLUSH
#else
    /*
    * use this to return a char from the current input buffer, or block if
    * no input is waiting.
    */
    #define FLAG TCSANOW

#endif

    if ((error = tcsetattr(0, FLAG, &Ntty)) == 0) {
        error  = read(0, &ch, 1 );        /* get char from stdin */
        error += tcsetattr(0, FLAG, &Otty);   /* restore old settings */
    }

    return (error == 1 ? (int) ch : -1 );
}
```

Comment: It works for me, and you should add "#include <termios.h>"

Answer (score 1):

kbhit() is non-standard.  In fact, I don't believe there is a standard function for detecting keyboard input.  The best you can do is read a character from stdin using e.g. fgetc, and hope it's not redirected from somewhere else.