# Confused about getchar() function

Tags: c, getchar

I am confused about `getchar()`'s role in the following code. I mean I know it's helping me see the output window which will only be closed when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

So `getchar()` is basically waiting for me to press enter and then reads a single character.

What is that single character this function is reading? I did not press any key from the keyboard for it to read.

Now when it's not reading anything, why does it not give an error saying "hey, you didn't enter anything for me to read"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "blah \n" );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: getchar() will keep waiting indefinitely until a key is pressed. Its your servant.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Newbie questions are totally OK here, as long as they are otherwise on-topic. Yours is actually a fairly good question, as it addresses an important concept.

Comment: Please try and keep your title close to the topic of the question, it will help others who are searching for something similar. I've edited your title to just reflect the question. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :) I will keep in mind what you said about title relevance. So glad I found this website today..been searching for one since long where my queries could be answered real quick...all the answers I got have been of great help..thanks to all of you guys :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `getchar()` function will simply wait until it receives a character, holding the program up until it does.

A character is sent when you hit the enter key; under a Windows OS, it will send a carriage return (CR) and a line-feed (LF).

See [this CodingHorror post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html) for a nicely put explanation.

*(...the explanation of the CR+LF part, not the `getchar()` blocking part)*

Answer (score 11):

That's because getchar() is a *blocking* function.

You should read about [blocking functions](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS359US359&q=blocking+functions&aq=f&aqi=g-m1&aql=&oq=), which basically make the process *wait* for something to happen.

The implementation of this *waiting* behavior depends on the function, but usually it's a loop that waits for some event to happen.

For the case of the `getchar()` function, this probably is implemented as a loop that constantly reads a file (stdin for this case) and checks weather the file is modified. If the file is modified, the loop behaves by doing something else.

Comment: I think I'll read up on them as well. Is that (based on the user's description) more like an event listener or an interrupt (or neither and I'm the one with the dumb questions)?

Comment: @Anthony: The internal implementation differs: When you directly access HW (as in reading from a serial port), it will usually be interrupt-driven. If you are reading from a console window in a GUI environment, getchar will probably receive some kind of event from the GUI framework.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ch;

    printf("I'm now going to block until you press something and then return... ");

    ch = getchar();

    if (ch >= 0)
       printf("\nYou pressed %c\n", ch);
    else
       printf("\nAliens have taken over standard input! Run!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

`getchar()` will cause your program to go to sleep until a keyboard (or whatever is attached to stdin) interrupt is received. This means it's blocking, no additional code will execute until `getchar()` returns.

It's very, very helpful to look at the *return value* of a function in order to understand it.

Any function may block, unless it provides some mechanism to prevent blocking. For instance, `open()` allows a `O_NONBLOCK` flag which is helpful for opening slow to respond devices like modems. In short, if it gets input from a terminal or has to wait to get an answer from the kernel or some device, there's a very good chance it might block.

Answer (score 2):

getchar() blocks your program's execution until a key is pressed. So, there's no error if no key is pressed, getchar() will wait for it to happen :)

Answer (score 1):

You can learn more about how getchar behaves here:
http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/getchar
...this should answer your question:)

Answer (score 0):

I think what confuses you is that the Enter key is needed befor the program continues. By default, the terminal will buffer all information until Enter is pressed, before even sending it to the C program.

see [discussion of Enter problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar)