# getchar() and stdin

Tags: c

A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426718/getchar-and-putchar), but my question is different.

But, I'd like to know more about the internals of getchar() and stdin. I know that getchar() just ultimately calls fgetc(stdin).

My question is about buffering, stdin and getchar() behavior. Given the classic K&R example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

It seems to me that getchar()'s behavior could be described as follows:

If there's nothing in the stdin buffer, let the OS accept user input until [enter] is pressed. Then return the first character in the buffer.

Assume the program is run and the user types "anchovies."

So, in the above code listing, the first call to getchar() awaits user input and assigns the first character in the buffer to variable c. Inside the loop, the first iteration's call to getchar() says "Hey, there's stuff in the buffer, return the next character in the buffer." But the Nth iteration of the while loop results in getchar() saying "Hey, there's nothing in the buffer, so let stdin gather what the user types.

I've spend a little time with the c source, but it seems this is more of a behavioral artifact of stdin rather than fgetc().

Am I wrong here? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I doubt it very very much the "classic K&R example" has the `fflush(stdin)` Undefined Behaviour! I can't check just right now ...

Comment: @pmg: You are right, I corrected the example.

Comment: Thanks, I must have pasted a dirty example that contained a bit of rubble from my experimenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that `getchar()` just ultimately calls `fgetc(stdin)`.

Not necessarily. `getchar` and `getc` might as well expand to the actual procedure of reading from a file, with `fgetc` implemented as

```
int fgetc(FILE *fp)
{
    return getc(fp);
}
```

> Hey, there's nothing in the buffer, so let stdin gather what the user types.
>   [...] it seems this is more of a behavioral artifact of `stdin` rather than `fgetc()`.

I can only tell you what I know, and that is how Unix/Linux works. On that platform, a `FILE` (including the thing that `stdin` points to) holds a file descriptor (an `int`) that is passed to the OS to indicate from which input source the `FILE` gets data, plus a buffer and some other bookkeeping stuff.

The "gather" part then means "call the `read` system call on the file descriptor to fill the buffer again". This varies per implementation of C, though.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So, at a high level, is my description of the general behavior correct? As in "Hey, there's nothing in the buffer, so gather some new input from stdin?"

Comment: @ybakos: yep, that's what happens. The `fgetc` implementation trick, btw., is not a fiction: IIRC, I saw this in the 4.4BSD UNIX C library, from which the one in Mac OS X is ultimately derived.

Answer (score 25):

The behaviour you're observing has nothing to do with C and `getchar()`, but with the teletype (TTY) subsystem in the OS kernel.

For this you need to know how processes get their input from your keyboard and how they write their output to your terminal window (I assume you use UNIX and the following explanations apply specifically to UNIX, i.e. Linux, macOS, etc.):

[image]

The box entitled "Terminal" in above diagram is your terminal window, e.g. xterm, iTerm, or Terminal.app. In the old times, terminals where separate hardware devices, consisting of a keyboard and a screen, and they were connected to a (possibly remote) computer over a serial line (RS-232). Every character typed on the terminal keyboard was sent over this line to the computer and consumed by an application that was connected to the terminal. And every character that the application produced as output was sent over the same line to the terminal which displayed it on the screen.

Nowadays, terminals are not hardware devices anymore, but they moved "inside" the computer and became processes that are referred to as **terminal emulators**. xterm, iTerm2, Terminal.app, etc., are all terminal emulators.

However, the communication mechanism between applications and terminal emulators **stayed the same** as it was for hardware terminals. Terminal emulators **emulate** hardware terminals. That means, from the point of view of an application, talking to a terminal emulator today (e.g. [iTerm2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2)) works the same as talking to a real terminal (e.g. a [DEC VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100)) back in 1979. This mechanism was left unchanged so that applications developed for hardware terminals would still work with software terminal emulators.

So how does this communication mechanism work? UNIX has a subsystem called **TTY** in the kernel (TTY stands for teletype, which was the earliest form of computer terminals that didn't even have a screen, just a keyboard and a printer). You can think of TTY as a **generic driver** for terminals. TTY reads bytes from the port to which a terminal is connected (coming from the keyboard of the terminal), and writes bytes to this port (being sent to the display of the terminal).

There is a TTY instance for every terminal that is connected to a computer (or for every terminal emulator process running on the computer). Therefore, a TTY instance is also referred to as a **TTY device** (from the point of view of an application, talking to a TTY instance is like talking to a terminal device). In the UNIX manner of making driver interfaces available as files, these TTY devices are surfaced as `/dev/tty*` in some form, for example, on macOS they are `/dev/ttys001`, `/dev/ttys002`, etc.

An application can have its standard streams (stdin, stdout, stderr) directed to a TTY device (in fact, this is the default, and you can find out to which TTY device your shell is connected with the `tty` command). This means that whatever the user types on the keyboard becomes the standard input of the application, and whatever the application writes to its standard output is sent to the terminal screen (or terminal window of a terminal emulator). All this happens through the TTY device, that is, the application only communicates with the TTY device (this type of driver) in the kernel.

Now, the crucial point: the TTY device does more than just passing every input character to the standard input of the application. By default, the TTY device applies a so-called **line discipline** to the received characters. That means, it locally buffers them and interprets *delete*, *backspace* and other line editing characters, and only passes them to standard input of the application when it receives a *carriage return* or *line feed*, which means that the user has finished entering and editing a whole line.

That means until the user hits *return*, `getchar()` doesn't see anything in stdin. It's like nothing had been typed so far. Only when the user hits *return*, the TTY device sends these characters to the standard input of the application, where `getchar()` immediately reads them as.

In that sense, there is nothing special about the behaviour of `getchar()`. It just immediately reads characters in stdin as they become available. The line buffering that you observe happens in the TTY device in the kernel.

Now to the interesting part: this TTY device can be configured. You can do it, for example, from a shell with the `stty` command. This allows you to configure almost every aspect of the line discipline that the TTY device applies to incoming characters. Or you can disable any processing whatsoever by setting the TTY device to **raw mode**. In this case, the TTY device forwards every received character immediately to stdin of the application without any form of editing.

If you enable raw mode in the TTY device, you will see that `getchar()` **immediately** receives every character that you type on the keyboard. The following C program demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>   // STDIN_FILENO, isatty(), ttyname()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit()
#include <termios.h>

int main() {
    struct termios tty_opts_backup, tty_opts_raw;

    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
      printf("Error: stdin is not a TTY\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("stdin is %s\n", ttyname(STDIN_FILENO));

    // Back up current TTY settings
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty_opts_backup);

    // Change TTY settings to raw mode
    cfmakeraw(&tty_opts_raw);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_opts_raw);

    // Read and print characters from stdin
    int c, i = 1;
    for (c = getchar(); c != 3; c = getchar()) {
        printf("%d. 0x%02x (0%02o)\r\n", i++, c, c);
    }
    printf("You typed 0x03 (003). Exiting.\r\n");

    // Restore previous TTY settings
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_opts_backup);
}
```

The program sets the current process' TTY device to raw mode, then uses `getchar()` to read and print characters from stdin in a loop. The characters are printed as ASCII codes in hexadecimal and octal notation. The program specially interprets the `ETX` character (ASCII code 0x03) as a trigger to terminate. You can produce this character on your keyboard by typing `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: This is a great answer, very comprehensive. IIUC, the terminal display everything I enter on keyboard immediately when I enter it. So it probably setup TTY in a way that similar to raw mode. Running the above program inside a terminal, that terminal stops printing whatever I enter and the only print to stdout is the program's output. So I guess setting TTY in this program also affects how it delivers bytes to stdin for the parent process (the terminal in this case).

Comment: I think the 'cfmakeraw' call doesn't fully initialize the structure, it just patches it to enter raw mode.

So you need to insert "tty_opts_raw = tty_opts_backup;" before calling it.

Comment: This is an excellent answer!  BTW, man:cfmakeraw shows the various termios flags it sets for "raw" mode.  I replaced the cfmakeraw call with the flag settings from the man page and the program went into an infinite loop. I had to kill from another screen and then `stty sane` to recover.  So I'll stick with the cfmakeraw call....

Answer (score 8):

getchar()'s input is line-buffered, and the input-buffer is limited, usually it's 4 kB. What you see at first is the echo of each character you're typing. When your press ENTER, then getchar() starts returning characters up to the LF (which is converted to CR-LF). When you keep on pressing keys without LF for some time, it stops echoing after 4096 characters, you have to press ENTER to continue.