# How do I properly utilize fgets() and strncmp() functions?

Tags: c

I am trying to secure some C code by utilizing the fgets() and strncmp() functions. The program runs fine, however, if I enter the correct password ("password") more than once it still indicates a correct password. Also, even when using fgets() the results (if longer than the 9 indicated in the buffer) still appear in the output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[9];
    int pass = 0;
    char password[] = "password";

    printf("\n Enter your password : \n");
    fgets(buffer, 9, stdin);

    if(strcmp(buffer, password))
    {
        printf ("\n Incorrect Password \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }

    if(pass)
    {
        printf ("\n Root privileges authorized \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want c++ post c++ code.

Comment: C is not C++. C++ is not C.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that fgets is taking the first 8 characters off the input and ignoring the rest. Obviously, if you are inviting a password you don't want to ignore any input! You might want to do something a little more fancy to ensure that you capture the full input.

My first two tries at answering this were wrong. Thanks to wildplasser for holding my feet to the fire.

So, the hack answer is: use a really big buffer. fgets is probably your easier solution there.

Alternatively, you could allocate memory dynamically as your input string exceeds your buffer.

But, just for fun, here is an implementation that breaks us out of the "line buffer" trap that I wasn't aware getchar was in.

For this, I leveraged a very beautiful comment here: [getchar() and stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741930/getchar-and-stdin)

PS: Ok, Ok, I *tested* it this time. It works. On my Mac.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, i;
    char buffer[9];
    struct termios tty_opts_default, tty_opts_raw;

    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
      printf("Error: stdin is not a TTY\n");
      return 1;
    }

    /* save tty settings for later. */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty_opts_default);

    /* put tty settings into raw mode. */
    cfmakeraw(&tty_opts_raw);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_opts_raw);

    /* NOW we can grab the input one character at a time. */
    c = getchar();
    while (i < 8 && c != EOF && c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
      /* Since we are collecting a pwd, we might want to enforce other
         password logic here, such as no control characters! */
      putchar('*');
      buffer[i++] = c;
      c = getchar();
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0';

    /* Restore default TTY settings */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_opts_default);

    /* Report results to user. */
    printf("\nPassword received.\n");
    printf("(It was '%s' -- don't tell anyone! Quick! Hide the terminal!)\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int`.  (and: your loop repeats the first character 8 times, followed by a NUL.)

Comment: Dang. Obviously, I hadn't. Sure looked good, though! Sometimes I learn more by answering questions poorly than I do by asking them. Thanks, wildplasser.

Comment: You can do it without character-at-a-time input. This is now `POSIX-C90`, which was probably not what the OP intended.

Comment: I know; I think I referenced those ways in the text. Given that I colossally screwed up my first attempts, I thought I would just have fun and figure out how to do it the way I had originally imagined it working.

Comment: it is still plain wrong.(except for the no-echo thing, which was not part of the original question) Did you test it, using "passwordXXXX" as input?

Comment: Yes, wildplasser... I did test it this time and while I admit to the asterix elaboration, it works as intended for me. At this point I will defer to your better experience, so if you would like to point out my error this time, I will happily receive it.

Comment: your reading stops at 8 characters+NUL. so: `passwordX` will be read as `password`, and pass  (falsely) when comparing to `password`

Comment: No: you can't type that X, because the allowed input stops after the 8th character and flow proceeds. This may be a stupid way to accept input, but it *was* my reading of the intention of the original question. Maybe my interpretation of the question was wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can type that  X, **but it wont be compared**. Leading to exactly the same behaviour as in the OQ.

Comment: That’s Iike saying you can keep typing in a window after it loses focus. You can hit the keyboard all you want...

Comment: There is no concept of focus in C .Please go back to JavaScript class.

Answer (score 0):

- `fgets()`reads the (CR+)LF too, and stores it into the buffer.
- But **only** if there is sufficient place!
- Otherwise, your buffer will contain the first `n-1` characters, plus a NUL character.

  So: allocate a large-enough buffer, and strip the CR/LF:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pass = 0;
    char password[] = "password";
    char buffer[3+ sizeof password];

    printf("\n Enter your password : \n");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    buffer[strcspn(buffer,"\r\n")]=0;

    if(strcmp(buffer, password))
    {
        printf ("\n Incorrect Password \n");
    }
   
    else
    {
        printf ("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }

    if(pass)
    {
        printf ("\n Root privileges authorized \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Using the 'sizeof' option will alleviate having a set number in the buffer in case passwords are longer. I will be sure to use this in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: This implies you're running on Windows. Better to use just `\n` and let the compiler adjust for the operating system.

Comment: No.If the`\r` is not encountered, it won't be removed. Also: input *could* come from a file or terminal. (This is the *oblivious* way)

Comment: +1 this is exactly the problem. Ensuring that the additional characters typed do not get truncated and return a false positive by adding to the buffer space is a good idea.

Comment: Of course, this one only works if you know the password size in advance...