# C programming getch(), getchar(), getche()

Tags: c

In C programming, there is a getche(), getch(), getchar(). I have seen these three but I'm confused. What's the difference?What are their function?

Comment: There's no `getche()` nor `getch()` function in (standard) C.

Comment: As for `getchar()`, [here's the documentation](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.6).

Comment: I'm kind of curious who told you getche, and getch existed, and or for which systems.

Comment: [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) is part of C - the other two came from the ancient (non-standard) [conio.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) from the MS-DOS era.

Comment: well, that was quick

Comment: @NovaArdent I get the impression that `getch` is still wildly popular, at least among beginning C programmers on Windows platforms.

Comment: I closed as dupe to an existing question and added an answer of my own also addressing `getche`.

Comment: I get the impression that Turbo C is still wildly popular... caused by an abundance of completely incompetent teachers in a certain eastern country where programming is popular.

Comment: I know what you are talking about @Lundin. Sad, but true.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, true. Institutions blindly hire people without proper knowledge/expertise at all. I've seen and experienced a number of them too :-(

Comment: I've also added [a longish answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180001/what-is-the-difference-between-getch-and-getchar/51173273#51173273) at the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180001/what-is-the-difference-between-getch-and-getchar).