# echoing of getchar and '\n' char from stdin

Tags: c, echo, stdin, getchar

I have already looked at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar) but i am still wondering if there is another way to stop 1) the terminal echoing with portabilty as this is an assignment and I have already had one java program crash and burn on my teachers computer 2) in my program i search for a `'\n'` char then if it isn't the first char use `getchar` then `putchar` till the next `'\n'` char which works fine when using redirected `stdin` but when I try using the program without redirection the enter key is always echoed, is this to do with the terminal echoing or do i need to check for a diffrent char apart from `'\n'`? I have also tried including `'/r'` and done lots of googling but it seems the answer to the echo is can't be done with portabilty?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int first_line(char);
int main(){
    
char c;

while((c = getchar())!=EOF){
    first_line(c);
}   

return 0;
}

int first_line(char c){
if (c != '\n'||c != '\r'){
    putchar(c);

    do{
        c = getchar();
        putchar(c);}
    while( c !='\n');
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks Lachlan

Comment: do you get the echo in the `do-while`  if so convert to `while((c=getchar()) != '\n')`

Comment: There is multi-platform portable way of turning off echo. For UNIX and similar platforms you probably have to use termcap, but that wont work for Windows.

Comment: Using `termios` to control character-at-a-time input and echoing is portable between systems that claim `posix` compatibility. Use of termios is shown in the second answer on the `similar question` page mentioned at the start of your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar  Also, note `getchar()` returns an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: @BrianSwift; Thanks I did see that but I don't want to risk a no compile at this stage if it isn't compatible but will give that a go just for interests sake anyway.

Comment: @UNECS if the instructor doesn't provide a system with the same build tools environment used for evaluating your submissions on which you can test your code before submitting, I'd suggest you configure a system (perhaps in a virtual machine) to match the instructors configuration as closely as practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start try with the following :

1)  the condition should be `if (c != '\n' && c != '\r')`

2)  and the while loop ,in case  if terminal is line buffered then you are better of using `getch`from ncurses library the library packages should be there for most platforms.

```
    while((c =getchar())!='\n') {
       putchar(c);
    }
```

Comment: If I use 1 as soon as there is a new line eg at the end of a line with text the program will exit an with 3 it will skip the newline at the end of a line resulting in lines not having correct spacing between them

Comment: thanks I've been looking for getch but could only find it In c.... Library will try curses

Comment: Thanks for the ncurses idea but as i have to send the assignment in uncompiled it won't work without using the -lncurses arg at the gcc complier will it? [link](http://math.hws.edu/orr/s04/cpsc225/curses.html)