# getch() waits for Enter key?

Tags: c, windows, getch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr)

I'm using C-Free 4 Standard on windows 7 and I writing a C program.

I'm using getch() as a function to pause the program, however, the character(s) pressed echos on the screen and it waits for the Enter key to be pressed before moving on (it doesn't look any different than how the scanf works). I tried getche(), and it works fine, although the echo appears.

What could be the problem with the getch() function?

Answer (score 2):

> The getch, wgetch, mvgetch and mvwgetch, routines read a character
>   from the window. In no-delay mode, if no input is waiting, the value
>   ERR is returned. In delay mode, the program waits until the system
>   passes text through to the program. Depending on the setting of
>   cbreak, this is after one character (cbreak mode), or after the first
>   newline (nocbreak mode). In half-delay mode, the program waits until a
>   character is typed or the specified timeout has been reached.

More or less the same method is used in Windows. You can use _getch() to get the input character available for the application without buffering.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there are several ways to `pause` the execution of your program until you enter something, one way to do that is by using [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) (which is part of the function set of `stdio.h` and an official standard library), It will do the same effect as `getch()` (this function is part of the functions set of [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) library which isn't an official library).

If your problem is that you want to avoid pressing `Enter` every time you enter a character  which is not very clear in your question), then read this: [How to avoid press enter with any getchar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar)

Comment: No, gethcar also echoes like getche