# getchar() without pressing 'enter' button

Tags: objective-c, c, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid press enter with any getchar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar)

I need to get keyboard pressed key in console Objective-C app without pressing 'Enter' button

This code reads pressed key code only after I press 'Enter'

```
int key;
key=getchar();
NSLog(@"%i", key);
```

I need something like this but without pressing 'Enter'.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, consoles are in 'canonical' mode which does a load of processing on the input and doesn't pass it to a process's open file descriptor until a new line is encountered. You want to put `stdin` into 'noncanonical' mode, to get the bytes as they arrive:

```
#include <termios.h>

struct termios terminal_info;
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &terminal_info);
terminal_info.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, terminal_info);
```

(you should check for errors returned by `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`, too.)