# Behavior of getchar() inside while loop

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
int c;

  while ( (c = getchar())  != EOF)
    putchar(c);

}
```

Now ,running the above program produces

> $./a.out thisisthelinewhosestoragelocationisamysterytome            **-- LINE1**
>   thisisthelinewhosestoragelocationisamysterytome                     **-- LINE2**

When i entered the characters of **LINE1** , i think the functions getchar() and putchar() , have been processing the characters , or am i wrong ?

Here is my question.

After i hit enter , my **LINE1** is duplicated exactly to **LINE2** , which means it should have been buffered elsewhere 
, so where is it stored ? Also why is it implemented this way ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar Compelling reason: This allows the user to modify the input (such as backspacing and retyping) before sending it to the program.

Comment: There are _many_ buffers in the way from the keyboard to the output, including but not limited to the kernel, the terminal program, and the actual standard I/O functions

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , As i have not used windows for a long while , another question is if this type of multiple buffering  linux specific ?

Comment: All operating systems and runtime systems have buffering. In fact it specified in the C standard that the I/O functions should be buffered by default.

Comment: @BartFriederichs , thanks for the link , i now got to know that a canonical mode is implemented in unix like systems , where the input is stored in the terminal buffer , and is dispatched to the program only if '\n' is encountered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program doesn't receive input from the shell until you've entered a whole line.

Comment: But where is it stored , till the line is finished ?

Comment: @BarathBushan It's stored in your terminal program.

Comment: yes i got to know , about the terminal buffering in linux , thanks for your answer

Comment: -1: the program does not receive input "from the shell", it receives it from the tty driver. And the buffer is not in a "terminal program", again, it's in the tty driver or line discipline.

Comment: @Celada feel free to contribute a full answer with all the details.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of the system is to buffer the input until it sees a newline so that you have the option of hitting backspace and making edits to the line before your program sees it.

Comment: yes , so is the input buffer implemented such that , the termminal actually sends the data to program after seeing '\n' ?

Comment: @BarathBushan - No, the terminal program just launches your program. Your program then calls the OS to read from stdin. Your program can also ask that the input not be buffered, then it will get each keystroke as it arrives (including backspaces and such). I don't know the details of where the buffering happens (kernel, drivers, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I will omit I/O mechanisms of the system to supply the input stream to your program and getting the output stream from it. (Since I don't know them)

The `getchar()` function simply *retrieves* **one** character from *stdin*. On the other way, `putchar()` just puts **one** character to the output stream (*stdout*). Thus, there is no buffer magic involved here, you're just getting what you would expect to get : a perfect copy of what has been put in *stdin* in *stdout*.