# Limit the cin to just only one

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im trying to find a way to limit my input type to just only one in the game Hangman without using the LetterFill. The hangman works perfectly and when you input more than 1 character (ex. ABC) it will accept it and input and 1 by 1 but my prof said that it should only input only 1 character and if there are more than 1 it will eliminate/ignore the other letters any idea how to do it?

Code:

```
    char x;
    cin >> x;
    if (guesses.find(x) == string::npos)
        guesses += x;
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028142/read-only-one-char-from-cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028142/read-only-one-char-from-cin)

Comment: Read in a `std::string` using `std::getline` and thn check of the `size()` of the string is 1, if not ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may be to ignore all the rest untill end of line, like:

```
char x;
cin >> x;
cin.ignore(256,'\n');
```

other solution (Good for unlimited size)

```
char x;
cin >> x;
while(cin.peek() != '\n')
   cin.ignore();
```

Comment: What if the line has more than 256 characters?

Comment: I'd just use `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');` instead for the `ignore` call.