# How to stop my code from reading next character?

Tags: c++, string, character

I just want to read sign character from user and after this ask whether he/she wants to repeat.

it is something like this:

```
cout << "Please now enter the sign (+-*/): ";
        cin >> *sign;
        cout <<endl;
```

and after some time:

```
cout << "Do you want to try again? (y - yes, anything else - no): ";
        cin >> *yn;
```

problem is that if user enters something like "+t" in the first time then 't' is automatically assigned to the second yn character.

So how I can prevent this?

Comment: What is `sign`? What is `yn`? Please provide [mcve]

Comment: sign is character pointer, same is yn.

Comment: so I was supposed to write assignement only using anonymus variable. Maybe you understand why I have them

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Read only one character from std::cin ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028142/read-only-one-char-from-cin))
2. Process only the first character character, i.e., `sign[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I will assume `sign` and `yn` are of type `char*` since you didn't specify it.

What would happen in that case is that the input stream would give one `char` to `*sign` and keep the remainder of the input for the next access to the stream. So what you need to do is flush it. You can do that by calling `ignore` on the stream with `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` and `'\n'` as arguments, like that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> //For std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()

int main()
{
    char* sign = new char;
    char* yn = new char;

    std::cout << "Please now enter the sign (+-*/): ";
    std::cin >> *sign;
    std::cout << std::endl; //This std::cout is useless, entering an input in std::cin already returns to a newline

    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //Like this

    std::cout << "Do you want to try again? (y - yes, anything else - no): ";
    std::cin >> *yn;

    std::cout << *sign << std::endl << *yn << std::endl;
    
    delete sign;
    delete yn;
}
```

The first argument tells `ignore` how many `char` to extract from the stream while the second tells it when to stop extracting.

[Here is a link to the cppreference page about ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Comment: Wow thanks, really appriciate that.  I don't understand this line: ```std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')``` but I will try to dig into it and analyze. Thanks again

Comment: @AndroMazmishvili Basically, std::cin is a stream. A stream is an object that can be written to or read from and stores what is written until it is read. If you don't read it entirely, like by just reading a `char` from it when multiple `char` were written to it, it will still have things stored inside the stream and the next time you will want to read, it will give you what was still stored inside. So you need to erase the stream's content which is what `ignore` does.
`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is just a number representing the maximum number or `char` inside a stream.

Comment: ohh clear, I get it now, excelent explanation