# C Ignore newline character \n using getline

Tags: c, character, newline, getline

I want to read in a variable number of strings in C using the

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

function. So I came up with the following code:

```
int main() {
    int number;
    char *line;
    size_t len;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
        line = NULL;
        getline(&line, &len, stdin);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

The problem, with above code is, that the first call of getline reads in the newline character (`'\n'`) which follows the entered number instead of the first string. Adding one of the following lines of code (denoted by `OPTION 1 resp. OPTION 2`) fixes the problem:

```
int main() {
    int number;
    char *line;
    size_t len;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    // fflush(stdin);                                            /* OPTION 1 */
        for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
        line = NULL;
        getline(&line, &len, stdin);
        // while (*line == '\n') getline(&line, &len, stdin);    /* OPTION 2 */
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

**My Questions:**

> Is adding one of these lines (`OPTION 1, OPTION 2`) the correct way of doing this?
>
> If so which one is to favor over the other?
>
> If not what would be the correct way?

Comment: You could just read another character after the number, or, if you don't know how many whitespaces will follow the number, you can read that as a line and then read the number from the string.

Comment: `getline()` for the number then `sscanf()` it. Don't mess with the rest of the code :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/4386427

Comment: @pmg `sscanf()` is not safe

Comment: Option 1 is undefined behaviour.        `getline()`  reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer containing the text into `*lineptr`.  The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was
 found.

Comment: Use it safely, @Mayur, tools are as safe as you make them. Plain addition (`i + j`) is not safe and seldom used safely.

Comment: @pmg Could you please share how the `sscanf()` would look like in this case?

Comment: @SebastianWilke `if (sscanf(line, "%d", &number) != 1) /* error */;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is adding one of these lines (OPTION 1, OPTION 2) the correct way of doing this?

OPTION 1 is undefined behavior according to the standard so I wouldn't recommend it even if it does work on your system.

OPTION 2 is better and it will "eat" the `'\n'` left by the `scanf` which is what you want. But it will also "eat" any later input just consisting of a newline.

If you just want to "eat" the newline from the input of `number` I'll probably do:

```
int main() {
   int number;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   getline(&line, &len, stdin);
   if (sscanf(line, "%d", &number) != 1)
   {
       // Illegal input
       exit(1);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
     // -------------------    line = NULL;   Delete this - see below
     getline(&line, &len, stdin);
     printf("%s", line);
   }
   free(line);
   retur 0;
}
```

Notice that you shall only set `line` to NULL in the start of the program. Setting it to NULL in each loop causes memory leaks. Also notice the `free(line)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing the memory leak out! "Alternatively, before calling **getline()**, `*lineptr` can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer `*n` bytes in size.  If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, **getline()** resizes it with realloc(3), updating `*lineptr` and `*n` as necessary." - see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

You are reading an integer from the `stdin`. However by hitting enter it automatically adds a "\n" at the end of your input.
So once `scanf` is done, there's a `"\n"` remaining in the stdin.

Take a look at this, which gives more details: [Remove \n after scanf() which read integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725517/remove-n-after-scanf-which-read-integer)

To get rid of the new line after `scanf`, one simple solution is to add a "\n" at the end of the format string:

```
int main() {
   int number;
   char *line;
   size_t len;
   scanf("%d\n", &number);
   for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
     line = NULL;
     getline(&line, &len, stdin);
     printf("%s", line);
   }
}
```

which scans for an integer followed by optional white space.

Comment: Option 1 (using `fflush(stdin)`) is not guaranteed to work on all C implementations. The Standard [specifically gives it as an example of UB](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2), though for **some implementations** it is Defined Behaviour.

Comment: @pmg Do you think using `getchar()` to remove the `\n` is a better one?

Comment: best is the stop using `scanf()` for user input. It has poor error recovery and is troublesome for unformatted user input -- *the `f` in `scanf` stands for "formatted"* :)