# Input numbers without using Enter [c]

Tags: c, input, numbers

How input the number of digits without using Enter
I can do it with Enter:

```
scanf("%4d",&num);
```

So how I can do that without press Enter?

Comment: Research some bit, show what you have tried...

Comment: [`man 3 scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) should help.

Comment: Never mind,the question of how input the number of digits without using Enter?

Comment: you can not, you have to deal with getch() or something like, (nb: getch() is not standard c).

Comment: If code runs in a hosted environment, redirect input like with `program < input.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the need to hit enter you need to disable `icanon` mode using the `ioctl` system call (or `stty` command - assuming you are using Linux). You probably want to use getchar instead of `scanf` and do your own input processing. It is very difficult.

You can maybe look at this post:

[How to avoid press enter with any getchar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar)

Answer (score 0):

as i said in comment above and as a reply to @Rabbid76

> getch() and putch() are non-standard functions defined in conio.h,
>   mostly used in turbo C/dev C++ environement. getchar() are putchar()
>   are standard functions defined in C standard and they can be used in
>   all environments. Yes, you can certainly write a program without these
>   4 functions
>   *from google*

but if some one insists here is how it can be (not handling negative numbers and backspace)

```
int inputDgits(int nb){
   int i=0;
   int j=0;
   char tmp;


   for( j=0; j < nb; ){
      tmp=getch();
      if (tmp>='0' && tmp<='9'){
          i *= 10;
          i += tmp-'0';
          j++;
          printf("%c",tmp);
      }else{
         // beep;
      }
   }
   return i;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you,but I mean to his:

```
int i = 0;
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    getche();
}
```