# Print something when Ctrl-L is pressed in C

Tags: c, onkeypress

How would I go about implementing something like the following in C:

```
if (isPressed("ctrl-L")==true)
    print("Hello, world");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to ASCII ctrl codes:

http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm

`Ctrl-L` is `0xOC`. So you need to check the return from `getchar` to see if `Ctrl-L` is pressed. Something along the line:

```
system ("/bin/stty raw"); // avoid the need to press Enter
int c = getchar();
if( c == 0x0C )
{
    // isPressed( "Ctrl-L" );
    printf("Hello, world");   
}
```

Note `getchar()` usually requires Enter. So if you want the effect immediately after `Ctrl-L` then you need to modify the terminal effect. Details can be found here: [How to avoid press enter with any getchar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar)

Comment: Hardly it would work.  Normally, the program receives the characters from tty only when the user hits Enter.  One needs ncurses or another library to detect keys pressed.

Comment: @user31264 true, that terminal behaviour is OS dependent.