# How to execute a command without needing to press enter? (UNIX, GETCH)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to simulate the history of a shell like script. The first step (at least from what I think) is to make it recognise the up or down arrows. Let me show you the code first:

```
string readSequence() {
    int c;
    string currLine;
    do {
       if (getchar() == '\033') { // if the first value is esc
            getchar(); // skip the [
            c = getchar(); // get the real value
                if(c == 'A') // the real value
                    cout << "up";
                if(c == 'B')
                    cout << "down";
        }
    } while(c != EOF || c != '\n');
}
```

Whenever I run this in the command line, if I press up down up down for instance, it will print `^[[A^[[B^[[A^[[B`, and after I press enter it will print `updownupdown`. I'm trying to make it print `up` or `down` as soon as the user presses up or down, and also make it not to print those `^[[A` or `^[[B` things.

Also, if you got any suggestions on how to do this in another way, please do share. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed

Comment: Is there a way to do this without any external libraries?

Comment: Is this C *or* C++? Please use *only* the appropriate tag as otherwise both communities will likely be peeved at you.

Comment: Possible dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar

Comment: The way to do this without an external library is to reimplement (some portions of) that library. I would not recommend it if you have a choice.