# Delay output till EOF rather than newline

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a program that copies input to output character by character on Linux terminal. The code is as follows (from Dennis Ritchie's C book)

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* copy input to output; 2nd version*/

main()
{
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
      putchar(c);
}
```

The program and its execution works fine. But I want a slight modification.

The output appears on terminal for each new line character (when I press enter). I want to delay the output till I signal the end of file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>. What modifications I have to do for the program in-order to delay my output on terminal.

Sample output I am getting is as follows:

```
abcd (enter)
abcd
llefn;elnf(enter)
llefn;elnf
(ctrl+d)
```

Sample output I wants to get is as follows:

```
abcd(enter)
llefn;elnf(ctrl+d)
abcd
llefn;elnf
```

Comment: Put the characters into a buffer and display the whole buffer and the end. There are no other options AFAIK

Comment: A fix that doesn't require changing the program is to write your input to a text file and then redirect that to your program as input, e.g. `a.out < input.txt`. That has the advantage that you don't have to retype the input when you test your program.

Comment: @MOehm Yeah, it is working fine without any extra space, but is it possible to do stuff using terminal itself?

Comment: This has to do with buffering. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798511/1254880

Answer (score 2):

You need to store these character's to buffer, **control indexes where are you writing** and when you receive `EOF` just print that buffer via `printf`.

If you cant solve it you can inspire here

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    int c, i = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (i < BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
        {
            buffer[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buffer);
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    buffer[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Work fine as long as `c` is not 0.  Likely OK for OP.

Comment: This code also outputs an extra `\n` every 1023 bytes, and an extra one at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

An easy, albeit sloppy and partial solution is to configure `stdout` to fully buffered with a large buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 32767);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- On a 32- or 64-bit system, you could make the buffer ridiculously large.
- Passing `NULL` to `setvbuf` lets it allocate the buffer with `malloc()`.

Comment: You can start with a big `size_t` value and divide by 2 until it is successful :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yes, I could write `for (size_t size = ~(size_t)0 >> 1; size; size >>= 1) { if (!setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, size) break; }` but that would be too cryptic for the OP's skill level.

Comment: What about if you dont know how big buffer you need but need program to be efficient ? Allocating amount of bytes doesnt sound very efficient. :-)

Comment: Buffering the output is just a quick fix that does not provide a full solution to the OP's problem.  Since it is unlikely he/she would input more than 32K bytes by hand in the terminal, it fits the purpose, but a complete solution would require allocating and reallocating a buffer as input keeps coming and potentially using a temporary file on disk if input exceeds available memory...

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591248/delay-output-till-eof-rather-than-newline#comment78141555_45591248): put the characters into a buffer and display the whole buffer at the end:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 #define BUF_SIZE 1024

 int main()
 {
      char str[BUF_SIZE]; // the buffer
      int c, i = 0;

      while (i < BUF_SIZE-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF)
         str[i++] = (char) c;

      str[i] = '\0';

      printf("%s\n", str); // display the contents of the buffer
 }
```

Comment: Don't write plain `main()`; it should be `int main()` at minimum and `int main(void)` for preference. That's been a standard requirement for all of this millennium.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Though OP is reading a book from the last millennium...

Answer (score 1):

You could set buffer to `stdout` with `setvbuf(3)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
        int c;
        char buf[BUFSIZ];
        setvbuf(stdout,buf,_IOFBF,BUFSIZ);
        while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)
                putchar(c);
}
```

The key here is the fully buffered mode specified with the `_IOFBF` constant.
The size of the buffer is set to `BUFSIZ` which usually equals 8192.

As was correctly pointed in the comments by Jonathan Leffler the limited size of the buffer may cause the program to suddenly spit out its contents garbling the terminal. To avoid that one could track the utilization of the buffer and extend its size when it gets filled.

Comment: That's okay if the file is smaller than the buffer size. Files are sometimes big.

Comment: I guess the world may have changed. Classically, `BUFSIZ` was usually 512. Even 8192 isn't all that big, though it's much bigger than I tend to think of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler since 1996 BUFSIZ in GNU/linux is 8192. Should be enough for interactive input from the terminal in most cases. I agree, to correctly implement the spec, we need to grow the buffer dynamically.

Comment: Note: per C11 "`BUFSIZ` shall be at least 256".  Smaller values occur these days in many an embedded processor.