# Using getchar() inside an infinite loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop, getchar

I want to input a character and get corresponding ASCII integer as output. I'm using getchar() to take input, create an infinite loop with while, the loop will break when 'q' is entered. My code is -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;

    printf("Enter a character(press q to exit):\n");

    while(1) {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d\n",c);

        if(c == 'q')
            break;
    }

    printf("End of the program");
    return 0;
}
```

The program is running fine when q is entered, exiting the program. But if I enter any other character, the numerical value is having a 10 added in the end. for example, if I enter i, the output is

```
Enter a character(press q to exit): 
i 
105
10
I
73
10
```

Any character is having that 10 added at the end. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 10 is the ASCII code for `\n`  (newline).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid press enter with any getchar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar)

Comment: I don't consider that a dupe, @MCG. It deals with how to get characters immediately (raw mode, basically). This is more asking where the `10` is coming from.

Comment: Yes, I was confused about where the 10 was coming from

Answer (score 2):

`10` is the ASCII linefeed character which is being placed in the buffer by virtue of the fact you're pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the end of each line.

If you want to ignore those characters, just don't act on them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int c;
    printf ("Enter a series of characters (q will exit): ");
    for (;;) {
        c = getchar();
        if ((c == 'q') || (c == EOF)) // stop if EOF or 'q'.
            break;
        if (c != '\n')                // only print non-newlines.
            printf ("%d\n", c);
    }
    printf ("End of the program");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I'm also checking for end of file in the loop, otherwise the return value will cause a rather annoying infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary job as a C-programmer when using `getchar()` is to **account for all characters in the input buffer**. When you enter `a` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>, `getchar();` reads `'a'`, but leaves the `'\n'` generated by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> in the *input buffer* `stdin`. On the next trip through the loop, the code would seem to bypass any prompts without waiting for input -- ***Why?***, because there is already a character for `getchar()` just waiting to be read -- the `'\n'`.

So any any of these *character-oriented* input problems, you have to put your *Accountant* hat on and account for each character left in `stdin`. There are several ways to do this. Paxdiablo has shown a very good approach. Another, similar approach, makes use of a helper function to *read and discard* all characters that remain in `stdin`. For example, if you meant to enter `'a'`, but a Cat stepped on the keyboard leaving `"asdfdeeees"` in the input buffer, after reading `'a'` the following characters remain `"sdfdeeees\n"`. You need a simple way to discard all characters that remain.

The following provides a simple-helper function called `empty_stdin` to do just that by reading continually until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered (it can return the last character (or `EOF`) to allow a check for the user manually cancelling input with a <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> on windoze.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* helper function - empty all chars that remain in stdin */
int empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();              /* get 1st char remaining in stdin */

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)   /* while not '\n' or EOF, get next */
        c = getchar();

    return c;
}

int main (void) {

    while (1) {     /* infinite loop for input */
        int c;

        printf ("Enter a character (press q to exit): ");
        c = getchar();                  /* read character   */

        if (c == '\n')                  /* is it a newline? */
            continue;                   /* if so, continue  */
        if (c == EOF) { /* end-of-file, from ctrl+d, or ctrl+z (windoze) */
            putchar ('\n');             /* tidy up with \n  */
            break;                      /* bail             */
        }
        if (c == 'q')                   /* did user quit?   */
            break;                      /* bail             */

        printf ("'%c' is integer: %d\n", c, c);

        if (empty_stdin() == EOF) {
            putchar ('\n');             /* tidy up with \n  */
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Below is the output of one session where single-characters, multiple-characters, (and no characters at all, simply <kbd>Return</kbd> pressed, and each of those possible scenarios are handled without issue:

```
$ ./bin/getchar_min
Enter a character (press q to exit): A
'A' is integer: 65
Enter a character (press q to exit): BC and other stuff
'B' is integer: 66
Enter a character (press q to exit):
Enter a character (press q to exit): Z
'Z' is integer: 90
Enter a character (press q to exit): a
'a' is integer: 97
Enter a character (press q to exit): z
'z' is integer: 122
Enter a character (press q to exit): Q
'Q' is integer: 81
Enter a character (press q to exit): q
```

Look things over, look over all answers, and put your accountant hat on. See how each that are successful, account for all characters in the buffer before prompting again for more input. Also critical is the check for `EOF` which is the only way a user has to signal a cancellation of input without using your `'q'` or generating a `SIGINT` interrupt signal with, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> on Linux. Let me know if you have any other questions.

---

**Edit**

Note: I added a 'tidy up with `\n`' after catching each `EOF` to provide a proper newline at the end of execution (so your next terminal prompt doesn't start after the last prompt for input from your program -- 1/2 way across the terminal `:)`

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it so nicely!

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the line

```
printf("%d\n",c);
```

to

```
 if (c != '\n') printf("%d\n",c);
```

As other pointed out, you were printing the newline character. With the 'if' above you make sure to only print characters that are not the newline.