# Using pthread_create to create a thread in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with `pthread_create`. I would like to make a thread to track the keyboard button, eg when I press the spacebar the program aborts the main loop.

Here is my code (create a thread):

```
void check_button_code(int *btn);
     // main 
    pthread_t trd;
    int btn = 1;
    pthread_create(&trd,NULL,check_button_code, &btn);
```

Action to break

```
void check_button_code(int *btn) {
    int a;
    printf("Press space to pause\n.");
    while (1) {
        a = getchar();
        if (a == 32) {
            *btn = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            printf("error %d\n", a);
        }
    }
    printf("zatrzymane\n");
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the error in the compilation, or at run time? The first problem I see is that the function should be returning `void*`, not `void`.

Comment: Can you add more details about your problem and/or error?

Comment: also, you should be passing `&check_button_code` to the function

Comment: Your thread function doesn't match the required prototype (signature) for a function called from `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Please provide a compilable example, or if it doesn't compile, all the code from the source file that doesn't compile (after you reduce it to a minimal example in both cases).

Comment: I think you should specify your compiler and environment that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to wait for the thread to complete. Add to main, before returning,

```
 pthread_join(trd, NULL);
```

Otherwise, the main thread ends just after the thread is created. Your *main()* function should look like

```
int main() {
    pthread_t trd;
    int btn = 1;
    pthread_create(&trd,NULL,(void*)check_button_code, &btn);
    pthread_join(trd, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Then `getchar()` will not render the char until CR is pressed. So, to make the thread read a space, you have to enter a space, then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

To deal with characters on the fly instead, see [this answer, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar). This way, <kbd>space</kbd> will be processed before waiting for <kbd>enter</kbd> to be pressed.