# C Program not exiting input mode

Tags: c, user-input

I'm trying to find out the number of tabs, spaces and newlines in my C program. The code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char c;
    int tabs=0 , spaces=0 , nl=0 ;
    printf("Provide the input");
    scanf("%c" , &c);
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
        spaces++;
        else if(c == '\n')
        nl++;
        else if(c == '\t')
        tabs++;
        scanf("%c" , &c);
    }
    printf("blanks:%d\nspaces:%d\nnewlines:%d" , spaces , tabs , nl);
}
```

Well, I'm expecting it to do just that but the code is just not moving beyond accepting the input phase. What am I doing wrong? Below is what my command line looks like:

```
[tejas@localhost The_C_Programming_Language]$ cc Exercise_1-8.c

[tejas@localhost The_C_Programming_Language]$ ./a.out

Provide the input seguiofgawie

gweuigwh

e u w   f qw[uwf            
[PHWUO FEFF 
qah fuwpfyh fweor
```

(I keep pressing the **Return** key but to no end. Please help. Thank you for reading. This is my first question, hope i didn't do anything wrong...)

**EDIT**: `getchar()` doesn't work either, and I'm currently using Fedora 26 and GEDIT as my text editor

**EDIT**: `getchar()` works, in order to send the EOF character, one should press Ctrl+D on an empty line and if you want it done in with just one press of the RETURN key, change your loop condition to `variable != '\n'`. I apologize for spreading misinformation.

Comment: EOF is not equal to Return. On most systems it is Ctrl + Z. But it still depends.

Comment: The return key == '\n' (on unix based OS'es), on Windows it's \r\n

Comment: (1) `scanf("%c" , &c);` never sets `c` to `EOF`. (2) `EOF` is not a valid value of type `char`. Please see `fgetc` and `getchar`, and pay close attention to their return type. (3) Identify the source that taught you to write `void main()` and never trust that person, book or web site again.

Comment: If you need to read the single key clicks, you have to set the terminal as RAW and then you may use fgetc or read and not scanf.

Comment: It works with `getchar`: https://ideone.com/CZxzKm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar

Comment: My suggestions are Linux based! Are you using Linux?

Comment: @SirJoBlack Yes. Also can you please tell how to write code in comments  and how to enter a newline? I've succesfully made  a fool of myself about 4 times already

Comment: What do you mean with the request: "How do I write code in comments?"

Comment: Like how @n.m. wrote   scanf("%c" , &c);

Comment: `void main()`? I can sense something ancient.

Comment: @n.m. Regards to (3)It's what we've been doing in college the entire semester...

Comment: @iBug I'm just doing what i was taught at college last semester... we also used turbo C and windows 7... This is my first I/O program in linux... god help me for the future...

Comment: I hear Turbo C was made mandatory in India by some misguided national school board officials. This was a really unfortunate decision. Try to stay as far away from Turbo C as you can. On Linux, use `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror` compiler options to compile all your C programs, and fix every warning religiously (don't just use type casts to silence them).

Comment: Regadring "getchar() doesn't work either": this is not a valid complaint, you need to show your code. In a Linux terminal, press Ctrl+D on an empty line to send eof.

Comment: To show code in comments, use backticks: \`int main\` -> `int main`

Comment: @n.m. okay the Ctrl+D made it work... I was wrongly blaming getchar(). I'll re edit my question to reflect this to not spread misinformation... thank you for taking the time. Thank you for the compiler flags.

Comment: If one of the answers given fixed your issue, you should [accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @dbush Both the answers recommend changing the type of  my `c` variable. It doesn't have to be changed. https://ideone.com/tTR80n#stdin

Answer (score 2):

There is a small error here that you are commiting, by comparing the scanned char value to EOF. Quoting another answer

> EOF is a macro which expands to an integer constant expression with type int and an implementation dependent negative value but is very commonly -1.

However, since you are reading from stdin, you won't be able to enter it as a single char since it will be considered as 2 characters and will not produce the desired result. 
In a nutshell, your program is behaving in the desired way. In order for it to exit input mode, just change your while condition to something which you are able to meet.

Comment: Thank you. This worked in Windows IIRC. One last thing: How can I write code in comments? Like the 3rd comment on my question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting This should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

i think, a character given by the user cannot be compared to EOF(end of file) as you are not dealing with any file i.e., you have not opened any file in order to verify its end.