# Print every character the user types without conio.h

Tags: c

I want to make a program that runs forever and takes a user input, something like

```
while(1)
{  
    if(currentkeybeingpressed != NULL)
    {
        print(the current character); /* So that the program just waits until a key is 
                        pressed and outputs the same letter the moment it is touched*/
    }
}
```

I want to do this on a KISS controller, which does not have the conio.h file ready to import and therefore I cannot use the getch function. Is there another way to find out what key is being pressed at the moment?

Comment: you can use scanf

Comment: What is a "KISS" controller? What functions *do* it have?

Comment: @yajiv is it possible to use scanf so that it doesn't wait for user input?

Comment: yup it is possible, put scanf in while loop

Comment: @yajiv how do I do that?

Comment: @yajiv The problem with `scanf` is that most of the time what it reads from is *buffered* and can't read single keys as they are depressed (or without echoing to the terminal).

Comment: @KidusAmare you can use getchar() which is available in stdio.h

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
   while(1){
       putchar(getchar());
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. This waits for user input and then press enter. I need it so that it doesn't wait and immediately repeats the letter it gets.