# How to avoid pressing enter in a portable context to empty the input buffer?

Tags: c, input, buffer, getch

### The Problem

I usually use `fgets()` or `getchar()`, but now I need to use `getch()`, because I don't want to press <kbd>enter</kbd> to send a char to the input buffer.

### What I tried

When I used `fgets()` and `getchar()` I also used:

```
int c;
while ((r = getchar()) != '\n' && r != EOF){}
```

But now if I use it before `getch()` it requires me to press <kbd>enter</kbd>, which I don't want.

Is there any portable solution to empty the input buffer?

Comment: If you want to use `getch` then you're not writing portable code to begin with. There is no standard C `getch` function.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Oh snap you're right. Thanks for the help, gotta come with something else up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `getch()` in a portable context [because it's a `conio.h`, not a `stdio.h` function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-getchar-getch-getc-getche/).
There are [lengthy  threads on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar) and the overall assumption is that it can't be done, only worked around in a dodgy manner.

I suggest you revise your code and application to check weather or not you *need* to input with a `getch()` like function, or if there are other ways to do achieve the same goal. Depending on the use case it's often only cosmetic not to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.