# Endles loop (while loop) runs until I press a key. Programming C

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I want to create a code in C, that runs a loop and breaks the loop when I hit '1' BUT without pressing ENTER after it.

I use the GCC compiler.

example Code:

While-loop has to run always without pause, until I press '1' but without hitting ENTER ...(bin/stty raw)

---

```
int c=0;
int leave=0;
system ("/bin/stty raw"); 
while ((leave=getchar()) != '1'){
        c++;
        printf("\n- - while loop nr. %d\n",c);
        sleep(1);
}
system ("/bin/stty cooked");
printf("\n-- end of loop...\n");*
...
```

---

Comment: Bitte, sprechen si English.

Comment: Hey KingOrgie, please replace the text in your language with english.

Comment: you need to use ncurses for that

Comment: @P__J_
nice thank you for the first....
can you show me how to realize it?

Comment: no - there are so many examples in the net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid pressing enter with getchar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar)

Comment: no it doesn´t :(.... @P__J__

Comment: @P__J__ no it doesnt... becouse the getchar avoids to pressing enter but at the end of every loop it wait for input....so the while-loop only loops again when i make a input ....but i like to have a while loop that run´s continuly and wait parallely for input....ughhh...

Answer (score 0):

This is a C FAQ, answered here: http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html

> Q: How can I read a single character from the keyboard without waiting for the RETURN key? How can I stop characters from being echoed on the screen as they're typed?

Basically, it is system-dependent and library-dependent. There are several possible solutions for various systems listed.