# Periodic thread terminated by pressing escape

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, allegro

I wrote the following code to implement a periodic thread terminated when someone presses escape. The result is a periodic thread that continues also after i pressed escape.
Can you tell me where is the error please? The compiler compiles without any error and warning. Before reading the code jump to EDIT below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <allegro.h>
#include <time.h>
 
void    *task(void *p);
void    time_add_ms(struct timespec *t, int ms);
 
int main()
{
int tret;
int a = 1;
 
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
 
    tret = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, task, (void*)&a);
 
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
 
    printf("Thread1 returns %d\n", tret);
    allegro_exit();
    return 0;
}
 
 
/* Sommare quantità temporale espressa in ms al tempo nella struttura timespec */
void    time_add_ms(struct timespec *t, int ms)
{
    t->tv_sec += ms / 1000;
    t->tv_nsec += (ms % 1000) * 1000000;
 
    if (t->tv_nsec > 1000000000){
        t->tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
        t->tv_sec += 1;
    }
}
 
/* Funzione da trasformare in task */
void    *task(void *p)
{
struct timespec t;
int period = 100;
int *pi;
char scan = 0;  
 
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
    time_add_ms(&t, period);
    pi = (int *)p;
 
    while (scan != KEY_ESC) {
        if (keypressed()) scan = readkey() >> 8;
        printf("This is TASK %d\n", *pi);
 
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &t, NULL);
        time_add_ms(&t, period);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: maybe i found the problem, when i press escape, it prints the symbol ^, so the compiler or allegro doen't recognize the esc key.

Comment: I suggest you change the key to some other key, to see if that key works any different. Also, I suggest you add some `fprintf` calls to `stderr` for debugging purposes. The stream `stderr` is better than `stdout` for debbuging purposes, because it is normally not buffered. A call to `printf` is equivalent to a `fprintf` call to `stdout`.

Comment: I suggest you make such an `fprintf` call to `stderr` as soon as the thread detects the keypress. That way, you can test if the keypress is being detected properly.

Comment: Hello @AndreasWenzel it's the first time i'm using this libraries and C (i did only a small course on C++)...maybe the problem is the keypressed because if i write the command "printf("Key in the buffer");" inside if (keypressed()), it doesn't print anything

Comment: I suggest you replace `printf("Key in the buffer");` with `fprintf( stderr, "Key in the buffer" );` for the reasons stated in my previous comments. It could be that you are seeing nothing because `stdout` (which is used by `printf`) is [buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/12149471). That's why an `fprintf` call to `stderr` is more reliable.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i tried with fprintf, but the result is the same: when i press a key, the string is not printed.

Comment: In your previous comment, you stated that you used `fprintf`, but not whether you used `stdout` or `stderr`. Using `stdout` would make it equivalent to `printf`. If you used `stderr` as I recommended to you, then this likely means that the line of code is never executed. You might want to set a breakpoint in a debugger to verify this.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i used fprintf( stderr, "Key in the buffer" );

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly finding the error, but I think it is what you want (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798833/11277878))

If you add following code to your `main()`, this will disable canonical mode, which will basically enable you to get characters immediately without waiting for a '\n' or EOF (or enter keypress in short) (already explained in the link above):

```
#include <termios.h>           
#include <unistd.h>    

int main(){
    static struct termios oldt, newt;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);  
    // rest of your code
}
```

And the thread loop here (I've changed it a little bit)

```
while (1) {
    printf("This is TASK %d\n", *pi);
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &t, NULL);
    time_add_ms(&t, period);
    if(getchar()==27) break;
}
```

Comment: Hello @grizzly, thank you for your answer...i need to hold the above format (i "cannot" add code) to satisfy someone. This someone uses the same strategy i used, but in my case there is something wrong.