# Get input without pressing the ENTER key - In C

Tags: c, input, getchar

As you can understand from the title, I want to get input from the user without pressing the ENTER key.

If I need to talk about the program I want to do:

I'm writing a keyboard speed test program. And as you can guess I want to get the input with the SPACE key, not the ENTER key.

The program I designed was like this:

Example text = "... an apple ..."
I will take every key the user presses and check if that key is an SPACE key .If this key is the SPACE key, I'll change to the new word.

I've reviewed other similar topics on this site. If what I wanted to tell was complicated or I couldn't explain it, let me say it. In games, it is enough to press the SPACE key to jump. There is no need to press the ENTER key.

I want something like this. And I want to do this using the standard library of c if possible. I don't want to use any 3rd party libraries.

One more addition: The function I want is a function similar to the getchar() function. The only difference; I want to get input without pressing the ENTER key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid pressing Enter with getchar() for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar-for-reading-a-single-character-only)

Comment: Unfortunately.          ,

Comment: There is no standard C library that does this. And there's no portable way to do this without a 3rd party library. So you're left with implementing code for every OS that you want to support. Which OS are you intending to support?

Comment: Hmm I get it. I will deviate from the topic a little bit but is it possible to do this with assembly programming language?

Comment: Is it possible to re-write Facebook in assembly? Of course it is "possible". But it is not practical to do so.

Comment: Yes, it can be done in assembly. No, that doesn't help you. An assembly language solution is even less portable than C.

Comment: Okay,  Thanks for everything :D