# C using getchar()

Tags: c, getchar

I have this following line of code:
`while((temp = getchar())!= EOF){printf("Hello");}`

I expected the program to print Hello for every char read, but it prints for every enter pressed instead. How can I change it to my intention?

Comment: It's obvious because enter is also a character defined in ASCII code

Comment: It's related to buffering. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar-for-reading-a-single-character-only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid pressing Enter with getchar() for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar-for-reading-a-single-character-only)

Comment: When you press enter, `getchar` starts reading from start of the line to the end.

Answer (score 0):

when you enter a character from the keyboard, every character goes into a buffer, including the enter(\n) character. getchar function will take each character in the buffer in turn and of course will include the enter character. You have to check the return character of getchar function is enter or not:

```
while ((temp = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (temp != '\n') {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }          
}
```

Comment: it still prints only when enter is pressed.

Comment: You want to print as soon as you type a character? If using getchar function,  very difficult. Because getchar gets the character from the buffer and to get the character into the buffer you have to press enter. Use kbhit() to check when you type a character and getch() to get character instead might solve your problem