# How to read only 4 digits in C

Tags: c

I want to get input from the user 1234 and when i press in the 4 digit to finish the scanf
I tried

```
    int num = 0;
    scanf("%4d",&num);
    getchar()
    printf("%d",num);
```

but it stopped only when I press enter and get the 4 first numbers , I don't want to press on enter I want to finish the input on the 4 digit and to get the number in num.
also is it possible to get the 4 numbers to 4 different variables

```
   int num = 0;
   int num2 = 0;
   int num3 = 0;
   int num4 = 0;
   scanf("%d%d%d%D",&num,&num2,&num3,&num4);
   getchar()
```

but it didn't work
also I can change the function of scanf to something else

Comment: You can't with standard C IO functions. You will need some kind of third party IO library such as `ncurses`

Comment: This may be of some help: [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: do you have an example for ncurses ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: @Yunnosch - no :(

Comment: Why not? Please explain which detail of your question is not covered in any of the many answers there.

Comment: Related: [How to avoid pressing Enter with getchar() for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar-for-reading-a-single-character-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input does not work like this. Your "standard input library" is *buffered*, it means it uses buffer, which holds characters. Pressing enter triggers that buffer to flush data  and then you can read it from your program.

You need unbuffered input, AFAIK, it is not easy-portable, so there is **no standard solution**.

So you have 2 options:

1. Press enter after entering the number, then you deal with input just like with a regular sequence of characters.
2. Or use library for unbuffered input.

For the second option there was a library called `conio.h` (it is pretty old), which implemented `getch()` method for unbuffered input, it is also implemented in ncursess.

Comment: could you give me an example how I can use getch() in my case ?\

Comment: how to getch() can help me in my case

Comment: The basic example (just to demonstrate how it works) --- https://pastebin.com/GqtZDwv7 .

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in standard C. You have to press enter. Basically, terminals used when C was created very often were sending data to the computer when the internal buffer was full or enter pressed. (Not counting punch tape and cards readers)

If you are happy to press enter after numbers are entered then:

```
int toNumber(char c)
{
    int result = 0;
    if(isdigit((unsigned char)c))
    {
        result = c - '0';
    }
    return result;
}

int isValid(const char *restrict str)
{
    int result = 0;
    if(strlen(str) == 4)
    {
        result = 1;
        while(*str)
        {
            if(!isdigit(*str++))
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char *removeLastLF(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str;
    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(*(str + 1)) str++;
        if(*str == '\n') *str = 0;
    }
    return wrk;
}

int main(void)
{
    char num[5];
    int var1, var2, var3, var4;

    fgets(num, 5, stdin);
    if(!isValid(removeLastLF(num))) printf("Wring format\n");
    else
    {
        var1 = toNumber(num[0]);
        var2 = toNumber(num[1]);
        var3 = toNumber(num[2]);
        var4 = toNumber(num[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , It is nice solution but I must to move to new line without enter

Comment: maybe I can do it with getche