# program that starts two threads and waits for their completion

Tags: c, linux, timeout, pthreads, mutex

My program contains two threads for which they are expected to end. I use a single variable that is shared between threads and this is `x` and a single mutex.
The `q` key ends the thread

Problems I want to solve:

1. I want the stars (`*`) that are displayed one by one on the line now, I want them to be one after the other on the same line
2. I don't want to have to press enter after `q` to exit the program. I want it to exit the program immediately when I press `q` (no additional keys)

What should I change?

P.S (I have two warnings when running the program with `gcc program.c -o program -lpthread`, but that's not what I'm interested in at the moment, I'll solve it later)

```
program.c: In function ‘first’:
program.c:24:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   24 | }
      | ^
program.c: In function ‘second’:
program.c:44:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   44 | }
      | ^
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_q = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

char *x;

void *first(void *arg) {

        x = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        do {
                scanf("%c", x);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
                if(x[0] == 'q') {
                        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_q);
                }
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        } while( x[0] != 'q');
        free(x);
        printf("exited thread 1\n");
}

void *second(void *arg) {

        struct timespec ts;
        int ok = 1;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        while(ok) {

                clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
                ts.tv_sec += 1;

                ok = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond_q, &mut, &ts);
                if(ok == 0) break;
                printf("*\n");

        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        printf("exited thread 2\n");
}

int main()
{
        pthread_t read;
        pthread_t write;

        pthread_create(&read, NULL, &first,NULL);
        pthread_create(&write, NULL, &second,NULL);
        pthread_join(read, NULL);
        pthread_join(write, NULL);

        pthread_cond_destroy(&cond_q);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `x` shared between both threads (not used in `second` or `main`), but if you do it will need to be protected. _I want it to exit the program immediately when I press q (no additional keys)_. This will require a non-standard solution I believe, something like ncurses. Also, not wrong but kind of silly to `malloc` a single char. Just declare `char x;` and forget `malloc`ing.

Comment: This is really two separate questions. I suggest you remove question 2 here.

Comment: For unbuffered input on Unix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798833/1717300

Comment: The title of the question linked to by [hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717300/hyde) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72031540/program-that-starts-two-threads-and-waits-for-their-completion#comment127277207_7203154) is [How to avoid pressing enter with `getchar()` for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798511/15168).  The top-voted answer is reasonable; the accepted answer is less reasonable.  (This deals with your second question — how to type `q` without having to hit the enter key too.)

Comment: You should fix those compiler warnings — they are telling you that your code is broken.  Add `return 0;` at the end of each function.  You are invoking undefined behaviour by not returning a value from the thread functions.  You can't afford to risk that.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that `first()` will run before `second()` — the allocation of memory for `x` (uninformative name — globals should be named descriptively) in `first()` is unsafe because it is not protected by the mutex.  OTOH, the thread in `second()` doesn't actually access `x`, so it isn't shared, despite comments that it is shared.  Also, allocating a single character via `malloc()` is hard work; why not just define `static char x;` and use that?  There is no obvious benefit to the dynamic allocation and it uses a lot more space that way.

Comment: Flush your output to display the star immediately: `fflush(stdout)`.