# How to handle key pressed in a Linux console in C?

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

I'm using Linux console and I would like to do a program which outputs random characters until ESC is pressed. How can I make such a keyboard handler?

Comment: similar and/or related - [C non-blocking keyboard input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/448944/203667)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getch()](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/man/html.CURSES/getch.CURSES.html) from Curses library perhaps? Also, you will need to use notimeout() to tell getch() not to wait for next keypress.

Comment: You should explicitly mention you're talking about the (N)curses library.

Comment: note: getch() from ncurses needs proper ncurses "screen" to be initialized, or it won't work.

Comment: You also have to initialize the library - which is a variation on what @ShinTakezou said.

Answer (score 29):

The line discipline for a terminal device often works in canonical mode by default. In this mode, the terminal driver doesn't present the buffer to userspace until the newline is seen (<kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed).

You can set the terminal into raw (non-canonical) mode by using `tcsetattr()` to manipulate the `termios` structure.    Clearing the `ECHO` and `ICANON` flags respectively disables echoing of characters as they are typed and causes read requests to be satisfied directly from the input queue.  Setting the values of `VTIME` and `VMIN` to zero in the `c_cc` array causes the read request (`fgetc()`) to return immediately rather than block; effectively polling stdin.  The call to `fgetc()` will return `EOF` if a character is not available in the stream.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>

int getkey() {
    int character;
    struct termios orig_term_attr;
    struct termios new_term_attr;

    /* set the terminal to raw mode */
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &orig_term_attr);
    memcpy(&new_term_attr, &orig_term_attr, sizeof(struct termios));
    new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
    new_term_attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    new_term_attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);

    /* read a character from the stdin stream without blocking */
    /*   returns EOF (-1) if no character is available */
    character = fgetc(stdin);

    /* restore the original terminal attributes */
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &orig_term_attr);

    return character;
}

int main()
{
    int key;

    /* initialize the random number generator */
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (;;) {
        key = getkey();
        /* terminate loop on ESC (0x1B) or Ctrl-D (0x04) on STDIN */
        if (key == 0x1B || key == 0x04) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            /* print random ASCII character between 0x20 - 0x7F */
            key = (rand() % 0x7F);
            printf("%c", ((key < 0x20) ? (key + 0x20) : key));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>Note: This code omits error checking for simplicity.</sup>

Comment: This seems to work but it also seems to provide the entire buffer each time. So if I press a then b then c, after the c press it displays aababc

Comment: @Jackie maybe do a `while (getchar() != EOF);` after `character = fgetc(stdin);`

Comment: Thank you so much for the great concise answer!

Answer (score 5):

change the tty settings for one key press:

```
int getch(void) {
      int c=0;

      struct termios org_opts, new_opts;
      int res=0;
          //-----  store old settings -----------
      res=tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &org_opts);
      assert(res==0);
          //---- set new terminal parms --------
      memcpy(&new_opts, &org_opts, sizeof(new_opts));
      new_opts.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL | ECHOPRT | ECHOKE | ICRNL);
      tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_opts);
      c=getchar();
          //------  restore old settings ---------
      res=tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &org_opts);
      assert(res==0);
      return(c);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `ICRNL` go into the `c_iflag` field, not the `c_lflag` field?

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <signal.h>

char * me = "Parent";

void sigkill(int signum)
{
    //printf("=== %s EXIT SIGNAL %d ===\n", me, signum);
    exit(0);
}

main()
{
    int pid = fork();
    signal(SIGINT, sigkill);
    signal(SIGQUIT, sigkill);
    signal(SIGTERM, sigkill);
    if(pid == 0) //IF CHILD
    {  
        int ch;
        me = "Child";
        while(1)
        {  
            ch = (rand() % 26) + 'A';   // limit range to ascii A-Z
            printf("%c",ch);
            fflush(stdout); // flush output buffer
            sleep(2);   // don't overwhelm
            if (1 == getppid())
            {  
                printf("=== CHILD EXIT SINCE PARENT DIED ===\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        printf("==CHILD EXIT NORMAL==\n");
    }
    else //PARENT PROCESS
    {  
        int ch;
        if((ch = getchar())==27)
            kill(pid, SIGINT);
        //printf("==PARENT EXIT NORMAL (ch=%d)==\n", ch);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

In this program u will only need to press `enter` after `esc` char,because `getchar()`is a blocking function.
Also u may remove or decrease sleep time for child process as ur need.

Comment: Except `getchar` waits for input, so no random characters will be outputted while `getchar` waits for user to press [enter].