# Press anykey to continue in Linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, key, cin, any

I am not sure if being in linux makes any different, but i have found online that this:

```
    cout << "Press Enter to Continue...";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

Should be sufficient, with `#include<limits>` in the header of course.

However, it does not seem to work in my program.

It compiles, it runs, but it does not wait.

Basically, i have a menu, which lead to a method call to display a list of people on the screen. I wish to pause that list before the system goes back to the menu.

Here is my code from the menu:

```
//Manager's Menu
void SelectionPage::showManagerMenu(){
    char option;
    while(true)
    {
        system("clear");                                                //Clears the terminal
        cout<<"             Flat Manager's Menu"<<endl<<endl;           //Display manager's menu
        cout << "Select Manager option" << endl;
        cout << "a) Add a new Flat Member" << endl;
        cout << "b) Delete an existing Flat Member" << endl;
        cout << "c) List Flat Members" << endl;
        cout << "d) Duties" <<endl;
        cout << "e) Resources" <<endl;
        cout << "f) Reset System" <<endl;
        cout << "q) Exit" << endl;
        cout << "make selection: ";
        cin >> option;

        switch(option) {                                                //Takes the user to the corresponding menu or method
            case 'a':   system("clear");
                        memberList.addNewFlatMember(points);
                    break;
            case 'b':   system("clear");
                        memberList.deleteFlatMember();
                    break;
            case 'c':   system("clear");
                        memberList.listFlatMembers();
                    break;
            case 'd':   system("clear");
                        showDutiesMenu();
                    break;
            case 'e':   system("clear");
                        showResourcesMenu();
                    break;
            case 'f':   //reset();
                    break;
            case 'q':   exit(0);
            default:    cout << "Option not recognised: " << option << endl;
                        showManagerMenu();  
        }
    }
}
```

the option i wish to select is c) which leads to:

```
//Show the current flat population
void MemberManagement::listFlatMembers(){
    cout<<"             Member List"<<endl<<endl;

    importFlatMembers();                                                //get flat member info from file

    for( int count = 0; count<flatMemberList.size(); count++){
        cout << count+1<<". "<<flatMemberList[count].getName() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Press any key to Continue...";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    return;

}
```

if you want to see any other bit of my code, feel free to let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rob's Rule #47: Never say `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *nix, terminals usually wait for a whole line of input before sending anything to the program. Which is why the example code you posted said `"Press Enter to Continue...";`, and then discarded everything until the next newline.

To avoid that, you should put your terminal in non-canonical mode, which can be done using the POSIX `termios(3)` functions, as explained in [How to check if a key was pressed in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962263/checking-if-a-key-was-pressed).

Comment: While that is excellent advice, it doesn't answer his question: why doesn't the `cin.ignore` block? (Not answering his question is understandable -- I see now that he actually didn't ask one.)

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't you just use [`cin.get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) (get one character)?

Comment: I have never seen this technique *not* be used.

Comment: i tried replacing cin.ignore with cin.get, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Do you think it could be that i've got a mistake somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from my code. It works in both windows and linux.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

// Clear and pause methods
#ifdef _WIN32
// For windows
void clearConsole() {
    system("cls");
}

void waitForAnyKey() {
    system("pause");
}
#elif __linux__
// For linux
void clearConsole() {
    system("clear");
}

void waitForAnyKey() {
    cout << "Press any key to continue...";
    system("read -s -N 1"); // Continues when pressed a key like windows
}

#endif

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    waitForAnyKey();
    clearConsole();
    return 0;
}
```