# How to implement "press to enter＂in c++

Tags: c++, key, iostream, cin

any idea on how to implement a "press any key to move on" in c++?

Based on my understanding, for any input stream function, it all requires users to hit "enter" to read.

But how do I make it like “whenever a key is being hit, it moves on to the next stage without hitting the enter key?"

By the way, the working station is Linux

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe this link could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862582/press-anykey-to-continue-in-linux-c

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in standard C++, since its OS specific. 
On Linux you can use Curses and getch in a loop until you get a character. 
Or you can simply use "Press enter to continue"

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch