# "Push-to-make" style use of keyboard keys

Tags: c, keyboard, ncurses, tui

I am using C in Fedora Linux to build a voice streaming application. I have audio running between two clients, but the next stage is to implement the user interface.

I am aiming to use different keyboard keys in a "push to talk" style, ie holding the "Q" key allows the user to talk to one user, "W" another and so on.

My question is, how would I go about implementing this? The transmit thread is just a while loop that reads 180 bytes from the sound card and sends it as a UDP packet. THe mist obvious issue is echoing of the key pressed, filling the screen with q's and w's, and how I can detect key down/key up in C. I am looking at `ncurses` but it is a big topic!

Any ideas or further reading would be greatly appreciated.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question, as to how to detect keypress without using `ncurses` is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293355/detecting-key-press-in-c-without-prompting-the-user) excellently, using `termios`, by @jim mcnamara

And `ncurses` doesn't seem to be as scary as it sounds :-). [Here](http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/srcs/curin1src.html) is an `ncurses` implementation which exactly ( almost ) satisfies your requirement. But according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984307/c-key-pressed-in-linux-console), you need to add a `notimeout()` call so that `getch()`(ncurses one) doesn't wait for next keypress.

Comment: ncurses does not detect key press/key release events.  You would need a lower level library to do that.

Comment: that helped out, I have realised that it would be easier to use a switching style mechanism for the call controls. You're right, ncurses isn't so bad I have managed to get a prototype going already!