# How to capture event "down" "up" for a keystroke or a mouse button in C

Tags: c, linux, cygwin

I found numerous examples that use either `X11` or `linux/input.h` unfortunately I am on Cygwin where `linux/input.h` does not exist.

I would like a simple example that I can use to detect events such as:

- Key down
- Key up

Or

- Mouse button down
- Mouse button up

I would like to find a solution that can work on Cygwin/Linux and as optionally on Windows/OSX.

Is it possible?

So far I've found 1 solution that is using X11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

char *key_name[] = {
    "first",
    "second (or middle)",
    "third",
    "fourth",  // :D
    "fivth"    // :|
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *display;
    XEvent xevent;
    Window window;

    if( (display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL )
        return -1;

    window = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    XAllowEvents(display, AsyncBoth, CurrentTime);

    XGrabPointer(display, 
                 window,
                 1, 
                 PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask , 
                 GrabModeAsync,
                 GrabModeAsync, 
                 None,
                 None,
                 CurrentTime);

    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &xevent);
        switch (xevent.type) {
            case ButtonPress:
                printf("Button pressed  : %s\n", key_name[xevent.xbutton.button - 1]);
                break;
            case ButtonRelease:
                printf("Button released : %s\n", key_name[xevent.xbutton.button - 1]);
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Building with

```
gcc foo.c -lX11
```

Unfortunately the Xserver has to be launched `startxwin&` and the mouse pointer has to be inside a X server window. So this is not a good solution.

Another approach was to use ncurses but It seems states `key-down`, `key-up` are not possible.

The example below does not work on cygwin because `conio.h` is not POSIX:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
char ch;
void main(){
    while(1){
        if(kbhit()){ //kbhit is 1 if a key has been pressed
            ch=getch();
            printf("pressed key was: %c", ch);
        }
    }
}
```

> conio.h is a C header file used mostly by MS-DOS compilers to provide
>   console input/output.[1] It is not part of the C standard library or
>   ISO C, nor is it defined by POSIX.

Comment: Have you done [a simple search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=cygwin%20C%20program%20capture%20keydown) to see if [there is an answer already somewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166074/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-key-has-been-pressed) ?

Comment: Good question and the answer is yes. I've tried many examples using `fcntl.h`, `termios.h`, `conio.h` or `linux/input.h` but I still did not succeed... Perhaps this is not an easy task...

Comment: You should include in your question what you tried and where it failed, so people could help you with that, instead of plainly asking for a packaged solution to your need. Stack Overflow is not about getting people to code for you :)

Comment: Well, this post is going to be very long :)

Comment: can you show us how do you compile program ?

Comment: `gcc -lX11 myfile.c -o myprogram`

Comment: I just discovered that it's much better to put `-lX11` at the end of gcc like `gcc -static foo.c -o test -lncurses`

Comment: Actually I've just edited my question. I tried to X11 example successfully but I have to start a x server and place the mouse pointer inside the X window which is not very convenient. I initially just want to capture the event "Keypress", "Keyreleased". I'm currently trying something with ncurses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to make a cross-platform program. I doubt you'll be able to resolve this problem with Linux-only libraries. What I suggest is to:

1. Ditch X in favor of Qt or GTK.
2. Make a module that listens to key events using facilities from `Windows.h`, compiled only if user is on Windows. Sooner or later you'll need to do that anyway for other stuff as your project grows.