# Detecting keyboard press in Ubuntu C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu

In `Ubuntu`, I would like to write a `C++` program which quits whenever the key `q` is pressed. Until this, the program continues running. But rather than just a loop which checks for input on every iteration, I want to call a function which then calls other functions etc. So, I cannot just keep checking for input in a loop because that loop is never revisited. Do I need to write a separate thread for this, which detects keyboard inputs, or is there something build into Ubuntu which I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [detecting key press in C without prompting the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293355/detecting-key-press-in-c-without-prompting-the-user)

Comment: This solution just runs a loop though, rather than running a separate thread and allowing the program to run normally in the meantime.

Comment: You never said it had to be in a thread. From your question: "Do I need to write a separate thread for this". If you have a requirement, state it clearly.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which environment is your program running.

If it runs on the desktop, it is a GUI application, and you need some graphical toolkit like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [Gtk](http://gtk.org) (to avoid direct [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) programming). You could consider also [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/)

If it runs in a terminal, you'll better use some terminal library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) (or, if you want a line edition, [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/)). Read also the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) web page. Notice that the console tty may be raw or cooked (in which case, line buffering happens partly in the kernel!).

You may also want some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (but Qt gives you one), so read about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

If you are not familiar with it, also read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Just read stdin and check if it's 'q'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace std;

void workerFun(const bool& stopFlag)
{
   //Do stuff
   if stopFlag
      return; // probably want to have some logic to clean up, save progress etc
}

int main()
{
    bool flag = false;
    //Start the worker in another thread
    boost::thread workerThread(workerFun, std::ref<bool>(flag));

    //Keep checking if the user wants to quit
    do
    {
       cout<<"Enter q to quit"<<endl;
       char input;
       cin>>input;
       flag = input == 'q' || input == 'Q'
    } while (!flag);
    //user want's to quit, wait for the worker to stop
    workerThread.join();

    cout << "Goodbye!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if instead of a loop, I want to call a function which does something. During the processing of that function, I also want the program to quit if 'p' is pressed. So, in this case, I cannot just wait until the function returns to check for input again.

Comment: That's tricky. How long does it take for the function to finish processing? You can have it run in a separate thread but then you have to signal the function to stop once the user presses 'q'. Is the function you want interrupted running in a loop?