# Stopping the program with any key(c++)

Tags: c++

How can i make a function that stops the program when a key is pressed?(the function needs to run as a thread).I tried this but doesn't work

```
  _getch() == true;

  if(_getch() == true){

    exit(0);

  }
```

Comment: It is operating system specific. The C++11 standard does not know about the keyboard. On Linux read [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and consider using [ncurses](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). BTW `_getch` is not a standard documented function

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293355/how-to-detect-key-presses-in-a-linux-c-gui-program-without-prompting-the-user

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ncurses](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses.tar.gz) library,

```
#include <ncurses.h>
... 
initscr();          /* Start curses mode   */
getch();            /* Wait for user input */
endwin();           /* End curses mode     */
...
```

You can find the documentation related to it at the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer exists at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773687/systempause-for-linux-g-c).

> The following works on windows and linux/unix:

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout << "Press \'Return\' to end." << std::endl;
cin.sync(); // instead of flush()
std::cin.get();
```

> The first `std::cin.sync()` clears the input que, the next command
>   waits for an input.

Comment: how i should use it|?

Comment: @MădeanDenis, you can use whatever you want. For example: add this to the function `void pause(){...};`