# How to check the character pressed in a C console program without pressing the Enter key?

Tags: c, keyboard, console-application

I have written a C console program meant to check the key pressed at any time the program is running. However I have to press ENTER each time to process the input from the keyboard. How to get the key pressed each time without having to press the ENTER key ? Here is what I have so far:

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RUNNING 1


int main()
{   printf("---------------------------------------------------------
 -------------\n\n");
    puts("Welcome to PUSH COUNTER appliction  :)");
    puts("Type any key to test here ...");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------
 -------------\n\n");
    while (RUNNING){

    char c = getchar();

    if(c != ' ') {
        printf("Not a space button... Program listening for push button .\n\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Finally pressed a space bar. Updating counter now ...\n");
        }
    }
     return(0);

}
```

Comment: This is OS-specific. What operating system?

Comment: I am using a mac OSX

Comment: platform dependent...in windows <conio.h> would be imported. I think in mac it is curses.h

Comment: On Unix systems, you have to put the terminal into 'raw' (or perhaps 'cbreak') mode — which is not entirely trivial — and then arrange that your program resets the original mode when the program exits.  Using a library such as the curses library can simplify that, at a cost in overhead.  Or you can get into the `tc*` functions and/or `<termios.h>` (for POSIX) to play with these properties.  See [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/) for some information about how this works.

Comment: The duplicate ([How to handle key pressed in a Linux console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984307/)) is tagged 'Linux' but it applies to POSIX systems reasonably generally.