Keyboard Input In Android Termux C++
I want to make simple games in the termux terminal in c++ and I need a way to get keyboard input into the game code like this :
void gameLoop() {
    char c = <the last key pressed>
    /*
    And here will be the code that will be executed
    continuously.
    */
}

First I tried to include the <conio.h> library but then I realized it is only for windows, so I found the <linux/input.h> library and included it.
It seemed to work at first because Termux is a Linux emulator so it has almost all of the Linux libraries.
But then I realized it needs to read a file named event1 located in the /dev/input directory, but I couldn't access it because because I am using Android. So I need a way to access it and read its contents or just use another library that can be used to get user input.

Have you tried termios?  An example of it can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984307/how-to-handle-key-pressed-in-a-linux-console-in-c
