# C++, monitor for keyboard input

Tags: c++, unix, input

I'm brushing up on my general programing skills and I've come across a snag. I'm writing a program that simulates a colony of bunnys. Once this program starts it is autonomous, however, at any point the user should be able to press the 'k' key to cull the population by half. I can't think of a way to do this without pausing the program to wait for user input. Nor can I think of a way to make it so that the program will respond immediately (the program runs in semi-real time using the sleep command). Is there a way to accomplish this without multi-treading and years more experience?

Comment: `I'm writing a program that simulates a colony of bunnys. Once this program starts it is autonomous` --- what do you have to do with the first bunny to get the program going?

Comment: the constructor for the colony seeds it with 5 bunnies randomly male or female

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944 -- although there's no C++ abstraction. Also check http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/asynchkbd.html

Answer (score 5):

I think this [article](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/) comes close to what you want to do w/o involving ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't know anything about keyboards, so any answer to this depends on your operating system and its libraries.

Comment: any idea where I should start looking?

Comment: Tell us what operating system(s) you want this code to work under.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Comment: *nix is what I'm using a.t.m.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ the [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx) Windows API call.  You should be able to find a suitable place to shoehorn this into your code to detect the keypress.

Comment: Regardint tpdis comment - absolutely correct - I'm assuming Windows.

Comment: know anything for *nix systems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is standard C++, but you can use a C function that checks whether a key is available:

```
#include <conio.h>

int wmain()
{
    if(_kbhit())
    {
        char ch = _getch();
    }
}
```

EDIT: as Zan Lynx mentioned, this is not standard C++, or even standard C, which is why there is no  header. It will work fine in Visual C++ or DOS C++ compilers.

Comment: It isn't standard, that is Windows-only.

Answer (score 0):

A library like Qt can help you quite a bit. You would create an "application" object, derived from `QCoreApplication`. In your override of `QCoreAPplication::event(Event*)`, you would handle the event if it's a `QKeyEvent` containing `Qt::Key_K`. This is portable across Windows, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try **ncurses** it's pretty standard in UNIX enviorments. It has special functions to wait for user input with timeout in case nobody press any key.