# How to instantly react to key pressing in C?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, keypress

I'm trying to call a function when a user presses a key, somewhat like sending a signal with Ctrl-C. The idea is to be doing something, say in a while loop, and actively listen for, say, the 'f' key being pressed. When it is pressed, the program will stop performing the loop and do something else because the 'f' key was pressed.

Is there a way to customize the signal mapping? I didn't have much luck with this. There also seemed to be 1 or 2 available signals for customization, but I need 3.

If I use getchar(), the user needs to press the 'f' key AND THEN press the enter key. I would like for them to just press the 'f' key and not have to press the enter key.

It is very similar to using unix's `more` program where the user can just press the space bar to go through pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows has the concept of hooks. I don't know what Unix has, but that might help you find what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for it in Unix.

Comment: Looks like you have ncurses or [this](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/). For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392291/c-monitor-for-keyboard-input

Comment: I've got an example of getting in and out of RAW mode with termios [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7411735/733077).

Comment: You can change your terminal settings to make 'f' send and interrupt signal with `stty intr f` although this is likely to drive you insane in most normal scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you do not like ncurses, you can try something like the following.

You can use a separate thread which uses `select()` on `stdin` then performs a `read()` on `stdin` and parses user input; if the key is what you are looking for, send a signal (i.e. `USER1` or `USER2` are unused) to your main thread. In your signal handler, perform whatever operation you are looking to do on the interrupt. Note that doing this means that your code must be interruptible so the interrupt does not break your computation.

Answer (score 3):

By far the simplest option is to use `ncurses`.

However, if that's not acceptable, POSIX (and therefore Linux too) defines a series of routines for 'terminal control' — the names start with `tc` and include:

- [`tcdrain()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcdrain.html)
- [`tcflow()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcflow.html)
- [`tcflush()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcflush.html)
- [`tcgetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetattr.html)
- [`tcgetpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetpgrp.html)
- [`tcgetsid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetsid.html)
- [`tcsendbreak()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsendbreak.html)
- [`tcsetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetattr.html)
- [`tcsetpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetpgrp.html)

In this context, you primarily need `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`.  You will need to study the strictures in the definitions for `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`, and will need to study the structures and flags in the [`<termios.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html) header.  Look at the `ICANON` local mode, for example: you will probably want to turn that off so that characters are available to read as soon as they are typed.