# How to read from the console without echo the chars

Tags: r, console

I was looking here and also in Google without any luck. I hope anyone can advise something.

I need to read from the R console and I need the input not to be echoed or masked as *** or blanks.

The only thing I found is:  [Is it possible to read from the console with scan without echoing the characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517986/is-it-possible-to-read-from-the-console-with-scan-without-echoing-the-characters) and I don't know how to do that.

If anyone knows a way to do this will be terrific.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: @ Tim   Windows. Sorry for missing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a native solution for `R` running in Windows.  However, I found [this terrific post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Masked-user-input-td924046.html) which uses the `tcltk` package.  The example generates a separate popup window into which the user can enter a masked password.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tim. I just tried and worked (even using R-Studio). Thanks for your help.