# c programming logic

Tags: c

I am trying to build a logic in c to come out from an infinite loop when  input is taken from the user otherwise continue looping. But the loop get halted and my program starts waiting for the input.
So, friends can you help me and suggest me some idea to implement the logic.
The os is linux code starts waiting at if conditon.

```
while(1) {
     recv(sock,&data,sizeof(data),0);
     printf("\nthe recieved data from the server is: %d\n",data);
     fflush(stdout);

     if (scanf("%c",&control)==1 && control=='b')
     {
         send(sock,&control,1,0);
         break;
     }
     else continue;
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Its hard to understand the real question without seeing the code.

Comment: What operating system?  How to do a non-blocking read for user input depends on your platform.

Comment: what is the code for your program. How can you expect help without showing what are you doing.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code. And make sure to format it so it displays all nice and fixed-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using a blocking function to obtain user input, so the program will halt on that function until the user inputs something.

Comment: can u suggest me a non-blocking function for user input

Comment: You could wait for input on a seperate thread. Also, take a look at this link: http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input