# can I display realtime feedback in a terminal game?

Tags: c, kbhit

I'm trying to write a simple terminal-based dungeon-style game in C, but I want to give the user real-time feedback on various processes that they affect.

I remember using kbhit() years ago, but I also remember the cpu going to 100% during the life of the program.  I'd like to avoid this entirely.  And I'm working in Linux now.

Let's say that you're in a dungeon in a text-based adventure game.  The dungeon is sealed off.  There's only so much air in the room.  The longer you remain there, the lower the oxygen gets.  I want to report the oxygen level in the room in real-time, while at the same time accepting commands from the user.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: The one idea I had was to use two terminal windows.  Commands are taken in one terminal, the results of those commands could be written to a text file.  The other terminal will have a program running that runs real-time stuff, and checks periodically on the same text file for updates on rates, etc.  Ideally, I'd like to do this in one window.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do what you're trying; are you asking for a library recommendation?

Comment: Try a loop that sets a timer and then waits for a specific time to elapse *or* [a key is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input).

Comment: @Jongware I was hoping someone would suggest a method more efficient than polling.

Comment: Just to be sure: [did you take a look at this related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input?lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is a way to do that. Have a look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). I think that is the way to go.