# Taking input without disturbing the program execution in c

Tags: c, io

I want to take input in a loop without stopping its execution i.e.

`

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<conio.h>
   int main()
   {
    char c;
      while(1)
      {

        if((c=getch())=='y')
                printf("yes\n") ;

        printf("no\n") ;
     }
      return 0;
   }
```

Now i want that "no" should be printed infinitely regardless of input and if i press y then yes should be printed.And then continuing from no again. Is this possible, any IDEA!

Comment: getch() will block on a read.  To do what you want, try doing a non-blocking read on STDIN_FILENO.

Comment: Threading---- Print `no` in one thread and the `yes` in another

Comment: @BhargavRao: Nonsense. That's not even a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: You could use `select()` or `poll()` in conjunction with `getch()` to ensure that it will be non-blocking.

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: @KenWhite Had tried that once and it had worked. But if it is crap, then even I'm enthusiastic about the answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao: 1) This is C, where there isn't much threading support. 2) A thread isn't even a viable suggestion for a solution, as it has nothing to do with anything a thread would solve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C non-blocking keyboard input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be on Windows and you're already using the old conio functions, you could double down with `_kbhit()`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    if(_kbhit() && getch() == 'y')
      printf("yes\n");

    printf("no\n") ;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`_kbhit()` "checks the console for a recent keystroke," according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx). What that means is that if `_kbhit()` is true, `getch()` will be able to get a character immediately and not block.