# Press Q to quit the loop

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am working on a simple code that keeps incrementing a counter every second and will stop incrementing only when a 'q' is pressed .

I tried getchar() and getline()  , but they require the user to enter an input for every loop .

to make it simpler , this code keeps counting on the console forever until I terminate it by ( Ctrl+c ) , I would like to use 'q' to do the same functionality.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
int j=0;
int main()
{
    printf("Enter Q to quit !\n");
    while(1)
    {
    j++;
    printf("%d\n",j);
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I see you are using Windows, so MSVC has `kbhit()` or `_kbhit()` to detect a key press, after which you call `getch()` or `_getch()` to get that keypress.

Comment: Really, "`system("cls");`" ? In 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Windows, so MSVC has `kbhit()` or `_kbhit()` to detect a key press, after which you call `getch()` or `_getch()` to get that keypress.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int j=0;
    printf("Enter Q to quit !\n");
    do {
        j++;
        printf("%d\n",j);
        Sleep(1000);
    } while (kbhit() == 0 || getch() != 'Q');
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the `while` not block on `getch`? Because of short circuit evaluation. If `kbhit == 0` is true, then `getch() != 'Q'` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you include `windows.h` makes me think you're looking for the [`kbhit()`](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html) function. From the linked page:

> This function is not defined as part of the ANSI C/C++ standard. It is generally used by Borland's family of compilers. It returns a non-zero integer if a key is in the keyboard buffer. It will not wait for a key to be pressed.

On UNIX/Linux, you have to resort to terminal mode manipulation as described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448982/99127) linked by @i_am_jorf.