# C Programming, how to run a for loop while waiting for user input

Tags: c, multithreading

for my coding assignment, I am having trouble.

The gist of what I want to achieve is to run a program that alternates a variable char OUTPUT between  'A' and 'B' every 1 minute. So the first minute, OUTPUT should be A. The second minute, it'll be B. So on and so forth.

However, if a user inputs the character P, OUTPUT will be P for a minute before returning to the A/B cycle.

I haven't exactly gotten code down yet, because none of my attempts have worked. I've tried using while and for loops. But every time I use scanf or getchar(), the program stops indefinitely to wait for the user input.

```
void timer(){
int t, d, change;
char p;

for(t = 1; t <= 30000; t++)
for(d = 1; d <= 30000; d++){
    if(t == 30000){
        change = 1;
    }
    else if(p == 'p'){
        change = 0;
    }  
    else{
        p = getchar();
    }
```

is sorta what I have right now. It's a rather incomplete function, but change is supposed to return 1 or 0 and in the main function, if it's 1, the OUTPUT will change to A/B.

I've also done some research and most people recommend multithreading, but we haven't learned that in class, so we can't use that for the program. I also don't have access to sleep() or delay(). Basically I'm restricted to the standard c library.

Comment: "Basically I'm restricted to the standard c library.", AFAIK thread are available in C11. What you ask require thread or some specific OS solution. Maybe you could use `alarm()`

Comment: You need a non-blocking input function like `pselect` or `poll` to indicate when input is ready on a file descriptor.

Comment: Stargateur, by standard c library, I actually just mean the content we've gone over. No way you could've know, but we also haven't gone over alarm().e

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck, then here is a short example using `pselect` (set to not block, e.g. both fields of `struct timespec` set to `0`). It simply uses an infinite loop to check `pselect` to determine whether input is waiting to be read on `stdin`. If so it reads the input and if the user entered a `P` (or any string beginning with `P`) `P` is output, once per-second for a time period, before the resuming with either `A` or `B` (whatever was not displayed last before 'P').

I have the time period currently set to `10 sec.` for testing, just adjust the `#define PERIOD 10` constant to change to whatever number of seconds you need (e.g. `60` in your case) I wasn't going to watch a minute each worth of `A's`, `B's` or `P's`...

The use of `pselect` is fairly straight forward. It is identical to `select` except for the `timeval` struct `select` uses for time and `select` has no `sigmask` parameter. (irrelevant here) The key is to set both fields of the `timespec` struct to `0` so that `pselect` will not block waiting for input. You simply call it, and if the return is `1`, then you have input waiting. Then it's just a matter of reading the input (I chose `fgets` so it would read and consume the trailing '\n'). Check whether the users entered `P` (by simply checking the first character in `buf`), if so, then begin a new period outputting `P`, otherwise simply continue plodding along with your `A` or `B` output. There are additional comments inline below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXC 64     /* size of buffer for fgets */
#define PERIOD 10   /* no. of seconds for alternating period */

/* simple function calling pselect, returns 1 when input waiting */
int haveinput (int filedes)
{
    fd_set set;
    struct timespec timeout;

    /* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
    FD_ZERO (&set);
    FD_SET (filedes, &set);

    /* Initialize the timeout data structure. */
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;     /* timeout 0 - immediately return, */
    timeout.tv_nsec = 0;    /* if NULL, blocks indefinitely.   */

    return pselect (filedes + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout, NULL);
}

int main (void)
{
    int c = 'A', 
        last = c;    /* holds last 'A' or 'B' for pickup after 'P' */
    unsigned long begin = time (NULL);  /* begin seconds of period */

    for (;;) {       /* loop until 'q' entered or EOF */
        unsigned long current = time (NULL);    /* current seconds */
        if (haveinput (STDIN_FILENO) == 1) {    /* is input ready? */
            char buf[MAXC] = "";                /* if so, get it!  */
            if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || *buf == 'q')
                break;                    /* if EOF or 'q' -- bail */
            if (*buf == 'P') {            /* if user entered 'P'   */
                c = 'P';                  /* set c = 'P' */
                begin = time (NULL);      /* restart time period   */
            }
        }
        else {
            putchar (c);        /* if no imput read, output char */
            fflush (stdout);    /* output is buffered so fflush  */
            sleep (1);          /* arbitrary second to wait */
        }
        if (current - begin >= PERIOD) {  /* end of period reached */
            if (last == 'A')            /* if last was 'A' use 'B' */
                c = last = 'B';
            else                        /* otherwise use 'A' */
                c = last = 'A';
            begin = time (NULL);        /* restart time period */
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** this is a 'nix specific solution. Windows does not provide `sys/select.h` (nor does MinGW). While windows provides a version of `select` through `Winsock2.h` and lib `Ws2_32.lib` it does not behave consistent with the implementation here.)

**Example Use/Output**

With an alternating period of 10 sec. instead of 60:

```
$ ./bin/pselect_abp
AAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAP
PPPPPPPPPPP
BBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAzz
AAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBB
AAAqA
```

Give it a try, look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you need, which is enable user input to change the periodic output, you will need to either:

1. Spin off a thread that will be doing the periodic output and change it based on the value of a variable in main thread that is set based on user input.
2. Do an async input read with select, such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/448982/4454124

Since you say you haven't covered threads yet, that's probably not the way you want to go right now, so I would suggest the select route, even though it's not standard C.