# ncurses window close on trigger keyboard arrow

Tags: c, ncurses

I try to monitor arrows with my program but when I press an arrow my window is closing...

```
void init_game(char *file)
{
    initscr();
    printw(file);
    while (1) {
        place_cursor();
        refresh();
        if (getch() == 27)
            break;
    }
    endwin();
}
```

`27` is the ESC key. I don't really understand why this append

Comment: The cursor keys might send escape sequences, sou may need to read `getch()` until no more keys are there.

Comment: How I can read getch() until no more keys are there? I don't understand this part of your comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input