# Non-blocking keyboard reading on macOS in C

Tags: c, macos, posix

I'm trying to implement a non-blocking keyboard input for `INKEY$` support in [my BASIC interpreter](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC). Reading the (many!) threads here on SO, I found what appears to be the [canonical solution under POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312185/kbhit-on-macos-to-detect-keypress):

```
static int getkey(void)
{
  int c;
  static struct termios oldState, newState;
  if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldState) == -1)
    return 0;
  newState = oldState;
  newState.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;  // use noncanonical input
  newState.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;    // disable echo
  newState.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;     // minimum chars to wait for
  newState.c_cc[VTIME] = CTIME; // minimum wait time
  if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &newState) == -1)
    return 0;
  c = getchar();
  if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &oldState) == -1)
    return 0;
  return c;
}
```

With newState.c_cc[VMIN] = 1, it stops and waits, but works as expected otherwise. Changing it to 0 stops it from waiting, but also results in c never being non-zero. I checked to see if the tcsetattr was failing and that was returning the 0 - nope, all good.

Does anyone actually have this working on any modern-ish macOS? I'm on 12.7.1 and Xcode 14.2, but I doubt there's been changes in this code since buttons were still blue and pulsating.

p.s. On a related note, the ECHO flag does not seem to have an effect in the Xcode console, but does work as expected in Terminal. I suppose that's not entirely surprising.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you post a *complete* MCV example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. You only want to call `tcsetattr` *once* during initialization (with `TCSANOW`).
2. Set `VMIN` to 0 and set `VTIME` to 0.
3. Don't use `getchar`. Don't intermix raw tty input with `stdio`. Use `read` instead.
4. You can use `cfmakeraw`, possibly with some additional tweaks.
5. You may have to do your own echo of an input char to output, depending upon the options used (e.g. `ECHO`, `OPOST`, etc.).

---

Here is some sample code (not compiled or tested):

```
struct termios tio_save;

void
ttyinit(int fd)
{
    struct termios tio;

    tcgetattr(fd,&tio);
    tio_save = tio;

    cfmakeraw(&tio);
    tio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&tio);
}

void
ttyrestore(int fd)
{

    tcsetattr(fd,TCSAFLUSH,&tio_save);
}

int
getkey(int fd)
{
    unsigned char buf[1];
    int len;

    len = read(fd,buf,1);

    if (len > 0)
        len = buf[0];

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig! With a few tweaks I was able to get it going. I see now that the issue was that I was constantly changing the settings. By doing it only once at program startup and again and program shutdown, it worked fine. But then my INPUT didn't work :-) so I had to add the restore and init around that fgets, and I was up and running. Thanks again!